# Starting out creating HTML email

Tags: html, html-email

I have designed an HTML page which I will send out as an email.
I have never sent an HTML email before and need some pointers.

Do you literally just send the code in the body of the email?
What is the best way to attach images?

I have tried Google but haven't found anything that helpful, answers on here are always more informative!

I'm slightly unsure how the whole process works!

Thanks!

Comment: could you add information on with what you'd like to send the mail? Outlook, GMail, Hotmail, custom script, ...?

Comment: "I have tried Google but haven't found anything that helpful, answers on here are always more informative!"

Comment: [Here's an answer][1] which contains a lot of useful pointers.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829254/best-practices-for-styling-html-emails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you literally just send the code in the body of the email?

No.

1. Rewrite the HTML and CSS to account for the many limitations of various HTML capable email clients and webmail systems.
2. Create a plain text alternative
3. Construct a multipart MIME email with the HTML and Text versions as alternate parts

The [Campaign Monitor: Resources](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/) section has a lot of useful information.

> What is the best way to attach images?

Generally speaking, link to external images. Otherwise the email file sizes will be huge.

Answer (score 0):

If its a normal HTML Mailer then yes, you just simply put everything inside the  tags inside, and attach images as you normally would using the .

When the user recived the email, if not in the trusted list, it wont load the images, and will ask the user if he/she wishes to load the remote images.

Hope this helps :)