# Remove spacing between table cells and rows

Tags: css, html-table, html-email

I'm designing an HTML email template, which [forces me to use tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829254/best-practices-for-styling-html-emails). In the code below, I'm having trouble (1) removing the spacing below the placeholder image and (2) removing the space between the image and the caption. Here's a screenshot of how it looks in Chrome 15 on OS X 10.6.8.:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Email Template</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <table style="border: 1px solid #b50b32; margin: 30px auto; width: 600px; padding: 0; border-spacing: none;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td id="main" style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
                <h2 style="color: #b50b32; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 22px; font-weight: normal; padding: 15px; margin: 25px 0; background-color: #fff;">Major headline goes here</h2>
                <table class="main-story-image" style="float: left; width: 180px; margin: 0 25px 25px 25px;">
                    <tr><td style="padding: 0; border: 1px solid red;"><img src="placeholder.jpg" width="180" height="130" style="border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;" alt="Placeholder" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td style="padding: 0; border: 1px solid red;"><p class="image-caption" style="background-color: #bebebe; color: #333; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 5px;">Caption.</p></td></tr>
                </table><!--/.main-story-image-->
                <p style="margin: 0 50px 25px 25px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                <p><a href="">Click here to read more </a></p>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </td><!--/#main-->
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The red borders are there only to show the outlines of the cells. I don't want them there in the final version.

Comment: I was able to fix problem (2) by adding cellspacing="0" and cellpadding="0" to the inner table element. However, the first problem persists. I can't figure out why there are extra pixels below the image in the same cell. Help?

Comment: "border-spacing: 0;" in CSS works for me...

Comment: Hello @JoeMornin, I am facing same problem but the difference is that on desktop `tr` showing correctly but on mobile devices spacing showing between `tr` and I tried all which are mention here but not working for me. If you have any idea please share.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It looks like the DOCTYPE is causing the image to display as an inline element. If I add `display: block` to the image, problem solved.

Comment: But if we have multiple images within a td, it destroys this.

Comment: Thank you, works perfect. To many people always suggest `border-collapse:collapse;`

Answer (score 84):

Add `border-collapse: collapse` into the `style` attribute value of the *inner* `table` element. You could alternatively add the attribute `cellspacing=0` there, but then you would have a double border between the cells.

I.e.:

```
<table class="main-story-image" style="float: left; width: 180px; margin: 0 25px 25px 25px; border-collapse: collapse">
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The borders are just placeholders so I can see the outlines of the cells. The problem is that there is extra space below the image.

Comment: This did the trick as I also have: display: inline-block; inside table and padding: 1em; and border: 0.5px solid gray; inside td/th.

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar problem. This helps me across main email clients.
Add:

- attributes `cellpadding="0"`, `cellspacing="0"` and `border="0"` to tables
- style `border-collapse: collapse;` to tables
- styles `padding: 0; margin: 0;` to each element
- and styles `font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;` to each element which is empty

Comment: For the sake of completness:In my case (I wanted to remove the spacing between [empty] cells), only the attributes were needed (in fact, only cellspacing='0'). All the styles did not change a thing, and after I added the attributes to the table tag, no styles were needed at all. Working in FF and Chrome.

Comment: Yes, this solution works in your case because you are solving the problem of removing spaces between cells in the HTML template displayed in browsers (not in e-mail clients).

However, this issue solves the problem of removing spaces between the elements in an email template, so this issue is more complex than yours.

Comment: Very well observed. I did not realize that this question aims on email templates. My bad.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but it didn't involve an HTML template. To remove the last bit of vertical space between two table cells, one above the other, I tried many things, including `border: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;` on the table cells, and             `border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;` on the table.  What actually worked was the `font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;` suggested here, so I thank you.

Answer (score 10):

You have `cellspacing="0"` twice, try replacing the second one with `cellpadding="0"` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Nothing has worked. The solution for the issue is.

```
<style>
table td {
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Old post but saved me some time, couldn't figure out what was causing that padding. Tnx!

Answer (score 7):

If you see table class it has border-spacing: 2px; You could override table class in your css and set its border-spacing: 0px!important in table; I did it like

```
table {
      border-collapse: separate;
      white-space: normal;
      line-height: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: medium;
      font-style: normal;
      color: -internal-quirk-inherit;
      text-align: start;
      border-spacing: 0px!important;
      font-variant: normal;   }
```

It saved my day.Hope it would be of help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Used `font-size:0` in parent `TD` which has the image.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by (inline)styling the td element as follows  :

```
<td style="display: block;">
```

This will work although its not the best practice. In my case I was working on a old template that had been styled using HTML tables.

Answer (score 1):

Hi as @andrew mentioned make `cellpadding = 0`, you still might have some space as you are using `table border=1`.

Answer (score 1):

Put `display:block` on the css for the cell, and `valign="top"` that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If the caption box is gray then you can try wrapping the image and the caption in a div with the same background color of gray---so a "div" tag before the "tr" tag...This will mask the gap because instead of being white, it will be gray and look like part of the gray caption.

Comment: Putting a `<div>` between `<tr>` elements wouldn't be recommended