# table td leaves unwanted space at the bottom

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="container">
                <img src="http://.../baking-potato.jpg" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The `td` cell is not wrapping "perfectly" the `div+img` content: as you can see from [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhFPE/1/), there's a margin in the bottom of the cell, highlighted by the black background.

How can I get rid of that unwanted margin? I tried the following css properties

```
table{
    border-spacing: 0 px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

but nothing changed..

Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove spacing between table cells and rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479090/remove-spacing-between-table-cells-and-rows)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add the following `CSS`

`.container img { display:block; }`

**[JSFiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/jhFPE/3/)**

**Reason**:

This happens because an `<img>` is an `inline` element, and therefore leaves space for text characters like `p` and `y` for example, because it is inheriting the `line-height`

Comment: That's the original JSFiddle. I think you need to click Update.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this occours here. I have tried several things. The following CSS seems to work for me:

```
.container img {
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}
```

However it's a hack and therefor not a really good practise in my opinion. But sometimes you just don't get around using hacks...

Comment: `not a really good practise in my opinion`. There you go, might be worth reading up on this :)

Answer (score 0):

Not really related to this case, but for someone having issue with `<pre>` wrapperd in `<td>`, you may need to set `margin: 0` to remove the space. This is the case I met with when using codeblock in hugo.