# css style emails for mobile to roll/stack on top of each other

Tags: html, css, mobile, html-email

I've been trying to style my emails like how Pinterest does it.
so in the web they show one way but in mobile they stack the td's on top of each other and things look bigger.
I'm very new to styling emails, any idea how to achieve this? or what to do and not to do?

Comment: Stack questions are for helping people when they are stuck with code or trying to understand something about a language. Asking for suggestions are considered to localized. Please edit your question to fit stack standards. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly mean, I revised the title, but if you have a better suggestion for wording this let me know

Answer (score 0):

Most email clients don't adhere to the same standards as web browsers. See this answer for some background on how to style emails. [Best practices for styling HTML emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829254/best-practices-for-styling-html-emails)

Answer (score 0):

Campaign Manager has a guide on creating mobile responsive emails - http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/

Answer (score 0):

I found out. 
I have to use @media in my stylesheet and also meta tag

```
  %meta{ name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1' }
```

some good tutorials:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3442/mobile-email-design-in-practice/
http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/18/from-monitor-to-mobile-optimizing-email-newsletters-with-css/