# Send email with Oracle

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I'm sending email in `Oracle 11g` with `apex_mail.send` function. I have below `html` structure. I have added `style` for `table` in this `html`. but when i open received email, `style` is not applied to the `table`. only text is visible.

How can i solve this ?

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>table{border-collapse:collapse;}table,td,th{border:1px solid grey;}td,th{padding:5px;}</style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table width="100%">
         <tr>
            <th scope="col">Company</th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">Reference</th>
            <th scope="col">Note</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>HNB</td>
            <td>226</td>
            <td>..952</td>
            <td>Insurance payment.</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>AC</td>
            <td>2150</td>
            <td>..255</td>
            <td>A/C service.</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practices for styling HTML emails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829254/best-practices-for-styling-html-emails) - I added the duplicate flag because what basically your question seems to come down to is 'why is my css in the head section not applied to my html in my email'. As you can see from the duplicate you you should be aware of several factors, not in the least the targetted mail client. Try to apply the styles inline and see what that does.