# Send Multiple Textbox Values in Mail Body using SMTP

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, email, sendmail

Guys I am trying to send mail through SMTP server. I am sending the mail using this code,

```
using(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage())
{
    message.To.Add(textBox1.Text); //TextBox1 = Send To
    message.Subject = textBox2.Text; //TextBox2 = Subject
    message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("email id");
    message.Body = textBox3.Text; //TextBox3 = Message Body

    using(System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient())
    {
        smtp.Host = "smtp.server.com";
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
}
```

Now this code works perfectly. Now I want to send a whole form in the body of the mail, like selecting values of multiple textboxes. This is the form, I want to send in the mail :

[image]

How can I design a message template so that it may send a message with body containing all the values you see in the above form?

Comment: It would be better, to use the `using statement` for your MailMessage and SmtpClient. Resources will be released after using with a `using statement`

Comment: Oh I see, I will use it. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @user333170 , may I edit your question, so using statements are used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("Name: " + tbName.Text);
sb.AppendLine("SurName: " + tbSurName.Text);
message.Body = sb.ToString();
```

or string.Format:

```
message.Body = string.Format(@"
   Name: {0} 
   SurName: {1}
", tbName.Text, tbSurName.Text);
```

I prefer `string.Format` version. There are many other ways like Array joining, but this two are all enough.

**Edit for HTML (from comment):**

```
message.Body = string.Format(@"
    <html>
      <body>
        <div>
          <span class=""name"">Name:</span> <span class=""value"">{0}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span class=""name"">SurName:</span> <span class=""value"">{1}</span>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>", tbName.Text, tbSurName.Text);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try this HTML method of string.format.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and build up a string from all of your textboxes in the desired format and assign it to `message.Body`

If you want the output to be displayed like your form you can add `HTML` to the string which will be rendered by the e-mail client, however you cannot use `CSS` for styling.

As an example:

```
    private string BuildMessageBody()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("<html>");
        builder.Append("<body>");

        // Custom HTML code could go here (I.e. a HTML table).
        builder.Append(TextBox1.Text); // Append the textbox value

        builder.Append("</body>");
        builder.Append("</html>");

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Then you could do:

```
message.Body = BuildMessageBody();
```

Remember to set the `IsBodyHtml` property to `true` for your `MailMessage`:

```
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

You could get slightly more complicated and iterate over your form for all textbox controls and build the string up this way, which would be a good solution IMO - however this should provide a starting point for what you need to achieve.

Comment: I haven't used StringBuilder before, can you give me a example with 2, 3 textbox values? How will I add HTML?  

Receiver will be using Outlook email client.

Comment: Thank you so much. Going to try your code. Much appreciated.

Comment: Basic CSS is possible, but the styles available are very limited; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829254/best-practices-for-styling-html-emails for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put an HTML file you can just set the MailMessage.BodyFormat property to MailFormat.Html, and then dump the contents of your html file to the MailMessage.Body property:

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(htmlFilePath)) // Path to your 
{                                                         // HTML file
    MailMessage myMail = new MailMessage();
    myMail.From = "from@microsoft.com";
    myMail.To = "to@microsoft.com";
    myMail.Subject = "HTML Message";
    myMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;

    myMail.Body = reader.ReadToEnd();  // Load the content from your file...
    //...
}
```

Otherwise you can use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create a body itself. If you click you will find an example and usage of StringBuilder