# CSS Colors lost in HTML Email

Tags: php, html, css, email

i tried sending an email dynamically using PHP Mail sending function and for some reasons my email is not displaying colors.

```
$to = $fetch_querygetemail['email'];
$subject = "report";
//$message = $_POST['allreportcont'];
$message = @"
<table style='width:700px; background-color:#F9F9F9; padding:20px;'>
<tbody><tr>
<td colspan='2'><span style='color:#f68e36; font-weight:bold !important;'>Coupons Sales</span> <span style='color:#333;'>(From: 2014-08-12 | To: 2014-08-29)</span><br>
<hr></td></tr>
<tr>
<td style='color:#333; padding-left:45px; width:300px;'>Coupons Offered</td>
<td>831</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='color:#333; padding-left:45px;'>Coupons Left</td>
<td>715</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='color:#333; padding-left:45px;'>Total Sold</td>
<td>193</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='color:#333; padding-left:45px;'>Sold &amp; Redeemed</td>
<td>18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='color:#333; padding-left:45px;'>Sold &amp; Unredeemed (Expired)</td>
<td>175</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='2'>&amp;nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='2'><span style='color:#f68e36; font-weight:bold !important;'>Amount Sales</span><br>
<hr></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='color:#333; padding-left:45px;'>Gross Sales</td>
<td>$2100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='color:#333; padding-left:45px;'>Discount Offered</td>
<td>$70</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Sales<sales@ashdjhsad.com>' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Email is delivered perfectly to my mailbox but not displaying CSS Colors, Width, how can I fix this?

On CSS of `<table style='width:700px; background-color:#F9F9F9; padding:20px;'>` is working no other inner CSS is working.

Comment: What Inbox using? did you try `color:#333 !important;`? Maybe it's because Inbox overwrite color style.

Comment: It seems your'e using `!important` in a wrong way.

Comment: @Moshtaf - Using Gmail, but !important too didn't work as I used font-weight:bold; !important; which didn't bold my text.

Comment: @Moshtaf - Yeah, sorry I just corrected it to `font-weight:bold !important;` in my code but still the same issue.

Comment: Did you try this? `<span style='color:#f68e36 !important; font-weight:bold !important;'>`

Comment: Welcome to the joys of HTML e-mail.  First off, don't send HTML e-mail yourself... use a pre-built class like Swiftmailer or similar to take care of it for you.  Otherwise, you have to worry about generating the headers yourself, which is not easy.  Next, understand that every e-mail client does it a bit differently.  Use a service like Litmus to test your e-mails to make sure they show up in the clients you care about.

Comment: @lock: i'm working with Gmail and send many email to that using code and don't have this problem. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/mq1w9xp4/ did your email look like different form this?

Comment: @Moshtaf - I did check this in jsfiddle and I am wondering why can't I see colors in Gmail also width not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `style` attribute, as not all email clients respect it.

Instead, you want to use old, ugly HTML4 code.

```
<td><font color="#333333>Coupons Offered</font></td>
```

See more about dealing with HTML emails on my answer here: [Best practices for styling HTML emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829254/best-practices-for-styling-html-emails/4829359#4829359)

Additionally, this support matrix is very useful when dealing with emails and your intended targets: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: No need for the font tag.  `<td style="color: #333">` works just fine.

Comment: How to set width? I even tried `<td width="300">` that too didn't work