# Convert Bootstrap css style into plain html

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, email

Does anybody meet this requirement: I use Bootstrap css to build a html page. And I want to send this html content by email. I can use "$('#myelement').html();" to get its detailed content. But it is without css style. How can I convert Bootstrap css style to plain html, like  ?

Really appericate your any idea.

Comment: You mean loke inline styling?

Comment: Is the goal of that is having a responsive email? If it is the case, It is not gone work unfortunatly, email clients rarely interpret "float" or even media queries

Comment: yes. i want to use the css style which already defined in bootstrap directly.

Comment: Thanks everybody's comment, I already get idea about it. I find a good link to do it, nothing with Bootstrap, but still useful for me: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770 
I will close this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Practices & Considerations when writing HTML Emails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229822/best-practices-considerations-when-writing-html-emails)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately most email clients will not accurately display an embedded stylesheet; you'll need to use inline styles and tables instead of floats, etc.  Check out this thread: [Best practices for styling HTML emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829254/best-practices-for-styling-html-emails).  [Hubspot](http://help.hubspot.com/articles/KCS_Article/Email/HubSpot-Email-Tool-Best-Practices) also does a great job of outlining some of the differences between web and email CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Emogrifier](https://github.com/jjriv/emogrifier) for converting External Css to Inline.

It will helps to convert and make reliable for E-mail view.

Answer (score 0):

There is whole lot of differences between standard HTML + CSS as rendered in modern browsers and what actually works in HTML based email.  The latter is much less standardised. Typically, you would expect to use inline styles rather than a embedded stylesheet for a lot of the CSS content to work.

This has already been discussed on this thread:
[Best Practices & Considerations when writing HTML Emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229822/best-practices-considerations-when-writing-html-emails)