# How to use Media Queries in email if <script> is stripped on email-forward?

Tags: html, email, media-queries, responsive

**Is it possible to create an email which retains both its HTML formatting and responsiveness when forwarded?**

If so, how do the big guys do it? Or do they just not worry about responsiveness when it comes to email? Maybe this is why their emails seem to lean towards being single-column as opposed to double?

I'm pretty new to emails, but on initial research it appears that many email clients strip the `<script>` tag when an email is forwarded. Consequentially, it is recommended to apply in-line styles. However media queries can't be placed in-line.

For what it's worth I'm hand-coding the emails, previewing them in Litums then dropping them into SendGrid.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Here is some info and references that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37647581/3597276

Comment: Hi @Michael_B. Thanks for the link, however I'm not sure that it has to do with media queries.

Comment: @TCannadySF, as far as im aware you cannot do inline media queries (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808233/is-it-possible-to-put-css-media-rules-inline) and the link provided by Michael_B talks about making sure that your CSS is inline. Generally percentage based tables are your best bet to get 'responsive' emails, but dynamically adjusting things like color, font-size etc isnt something i would imagine would be a straightforward process

Comment: you could try flexbox - https://litmus.com/community/discussions/1500-using-flexbox-in-an-email