# Flex / Grid properties are deleted in gmail email

Tags: php, css, flexbox, gmail, css-grid

I have a script in PHP that sends the following HTML by mail :

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
   <body>
      <div style="width: 70%;background-color: #060b2b;margin: auto;flex-direction: column;display: flex;">

        <h1 style="margin-top: 50px;color: white;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">Vous avez reçu une nouvelle notification.</h1>

        <div style="width: 80%;padding: 50px;margin-top: 50px;background-color: #222;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;display: flex;">
            <p style="color:white;margin: auto;text-align: center;">{{$notification}}</p>
        </div>

        <a href="" style="margin-top: 50px;margin-bottom: 50px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;color: white;padding:15px;background-color: #0E0E0E;">Accéder à mon compte</a>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

But the email received (when I inspect the main div) doesn't show the property `flex-direction: column;`

It seems that gmail filters those properties ?

Is this normal ?

Comment: did you find a better solution?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Designing HTML e-mails is not like designing HTML websites. There's a huge technology gap between e-mail clients and web browsers. It's as if browsers keep evolving, but e-mail clients are stuck in 1998.

In the world of HTML e-mail:

- embedded and external styles are bad,
- CSS3 is bad,
- JavaScript is bad,

**while...** inline styles and tables are good.

In the world of HTML e-mail, old-school layout methods are the most reliable. So it's not surprising that Gmail will strip out CSS3 properties. Your best bet is to stick to tables and inline styles.

---

**UPDATE: [Gmail now supports embedded styles.](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css)**

---

More information:

- [CSS in HTML Email](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/ways-to-build/css-in-html-email)
- [Best practices for styling HTML emails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4829254/3597276)
- [Best Practices & Considerations when writing HTML Emails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2229822/3597276)