# CSS properties not appearing in email

Tags: html, css, ruby, email, spree

In my [spree](https://github.com/spree/spree) store, I am preparing mailer to send email on order confirmation, but CSS property: `justify-content` is not appearing in the email rendered.

Following is my HTML:

```
  <div class="banner">
    <img class="height-50perc banner-content" src="https://myUrl" />
    <span class="banner-content">Order confirmed</span>
  </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.banner {
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #2e3092 , #0c5fdc);
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.banner-content {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

But in email rendered, I don't see property: `justify-content`. When I inspect corresponding element: it is like this:

```
<div class="m_2586726072602943149banner" style="background:linear-gradient(90deg,#2e3092,#0c5fdc);display:flex;height:80px">
    ....
</div>
```

Notice there is no `justify-content` in this `div`. I am viewing email in chrome and firefox browser in Mac.

I have also tried changing CSS to:

```
.banner {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #2e3092 , #0c5fdc);
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
}
```

But this also did not help.

Comment: If you are attaching any css files, then it won't work. Try adding the property inline.

Comment: @hunzaboy Tried both ways, actually spree takes care of CSS files, thats why other properties are coming, but tried giving this as inline as well. didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate: [**Flex-box properties are deleted in gmail email**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39376710/3597276)

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37647378/3597276

Answer (score 2):

It seems support of flex is still not proper as explained in this [link](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/1500-using-flexbox-in-an-email)

> Now here are the webmails in which Flexbox is not supported :
>
> - Yahoo
> - Gmail
> - Outlook.com
>
> Gmail and Outlook.com also filter every properties related to Flexbox, except the property `display:flex`.

This may be the reason why I am not even able to see the `justify-content` in rendered email.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference not all CSS reference is supported in E-mail providers, which is causing such error, each email provider has their own style and support.

You can find the full support list for [Gmail from this link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css):

and the other emails from [the mailchimp](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/)