# Set text in bold and vertical space with Django EmailMessage

Tags: python, django

In my script, User fills a Django form then two things : data are saved in my database and an email is sent to a support account.

I'm looking for improve this little part from my Django web application. All this process works fine, but I would like to improve this part in my view :

```
subject = "Ticket n° " + str(post.id) + " : " + str(post.Objet.encode('utf-8'))
            message = "Bonjour Datasystems, \n \n Vous avez un nouveau ticket en attente comportant les informations suivantes : \n " + "Nom : " + str(post.Nom.encode('utf-8')) + " \n Prénom : " + str(post.Prenom.encode('utf-8')) + " \n Société/Association client : " + str(request.user.last_name.encode("utf-8")) + " \n N° Téléphone : " + str(post.Telephone.encode("utf-8")) + " \n Adresse Email : " + str(post.Mail.encode("utf-8")) + " \n Description du problème : " + str(post.Description.encode("utf-8")) 
            image = post.Image

            mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, 'support@datasystems.fr', ['support@datasystems.fr'], html_message='This is <b>HTML</b> Content')
            mail.attach_file(image.path)
            mail.send()
```

I would like to write this part with bold character before each variable.

For example in my email :

- Nom : test (currently)
- **Nom** : test (What I would like to get)

And make vertical space where I put both `\n` :

For example :

```
Bonjour Datasystems, 
Vous avez un nouveau ticket ... (currently)

---

Bonjour Datasystems, 

Vous avez un nouveau ticket ... (What I would like to get)
```

Up to now, my email looks like this :

[image]

Do you have any solution according to my both issues ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make two templates; let's call them `message.txt` for text version and `message.html` for the html one. Render them and pass the results to `EmailMessage()`:

```
from django.template.loader import get_template

context = {
            'Nom' : str(post.Nom.encode('utf-8')),
            'Prenom' : str(post.Prenom.encode('utf-8')),
            'Telephone' : str(post.Telephone.encode('utf-8')),
            'Email' : str(post.Mail.encode('utf-8')),
            'Objet' : str(post.Objet.encode('utf-8')),
            'Description' : str(post.Description.encode('utf-8')),
            'Client' : str(request.user.last_name.encode("utf-8")),
        }

        message = get_template('message.txt').render(context)
        html_message = get_template('message.html').render(context)
        subject = "Ticket n° " + str(post.id) + " : " + str(post.Objet.encode('utf-8'))

        image = post.Image

        mail = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message, 'support@datasystems.fr', ['support@datasystems.fr'])
        mail.attach_alternative(html_message, "text/html")
        mail.attach_file(image.path)
        mail.send()
```

Example `message.txt`:

```
Bonjour Datasystems,

Vous avez un nouveau ticket en attente comportant les informations suivantes :

Nom : {{ nom }}
foo : {{ bar }}
```

Example `message.html`:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Bonjour Datasystems,</h1>

    <p>Vous avez un nouveau ticket en attente comportant les informations suivantes :</p><br><br>
    <p>
        <strong>Nom</strong> : {{ nom }}<br>
        <strong>foo</strong> : {{ bar }}
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was reading something like this. What is the difference between content in .txt and .html ? It's the same file with a different extension ? Then, if I want to call django variable `str(post.Nom.encode('utf-8'))` in my html or txt file, I just have to write `'nom'` ?

Comment: `.txt` should contain text version of your message and `.html`, well, the html one. I've added examples to my answer. The variables are used like `{{ nom }}` - these templates use standard Django template syntax.

Comment: Thank you ! I updated your answer and I will edit part from your answer ;)
CSS works with EmailMessage ?

Comment: For CSS support please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4829306/3570352)