# fixed width of div in oracle function

Tags: html, css, oracle, oracle-apex

I have oracle function to format mail data before sending. Function is called by pl/sql process in apex. But i have small problem with css formating of mail. I want to have div with fixed width to 750px. And my table and other elements will fit to this specifed width. Problem is that when i define fixed width of div it does not work. I have tried it on jsfiddle and it works but it does not work in oracle function. When i define other div parameter as font size, color, border etc. it works. But i am not able to change width of div. This is my function:

```
 create or replace FUNCTION  "SEND_MAIL" RETURN varchar2
    AS
     PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
     kontr_tema varchar2(500);
     komentar varchar2(2000);
     obl varchar2 (100);
     riz varchar2 (1);
     riz_warning varchar2(100);
     last_report_id number;
     vystup varchar2(2601);

    begin

    select RIZIKO into riz from AUDIT_REPORTS
    where REPORT_ID =
    (select max(REPORT_ID) from AUDIT_REPORTS);

    select OBLAST into obl from AUDIT_REPORTS
    where REPORT_ID =
    (select max(REPORT_ID) from AUDIT_REPORTS);

    FOR x in(select OPIS_KONTROLY  from AUDIT_REPORTS
    where REPORT_ID =
    (select max(REPORT_ID) from AUDIT_REPORTS))
    loop
    komentar := ''||x.OPIS_KONTROLY||'<br />';
    end loop;

    FOR x1 in(select KONTROLNA_TEMA  from AUDIT_REPORTS
    where REPORT_ID =
    (select max(REPORT_ID) from AUDIT_REPORTS))
    loop
    kontr_tema := ''||x1.KONTROLNA_TEMA||'<br />';
    end loop;



    vystup := '
    <html>
    <head>

     <style type="text/css">
        div{
          position:relative;
          width:750px;
          border: 1px solid black;
          border-collapse: separate;
        }
        </style>

        <style type="text/css">
        "table,th,td" {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: separate;
            width:100% !important;
        }
        </style>

    </head>    
    <body> 

     <div> 

     <table border = "1">

           <tr>
                <th>Oblasť</th>
                <th>Riziko</th>
                <th>Kontrolná téma</th>
                <th>Komentár</th>
             </tr>

             <tr>
                <td>'||obl||'</td>
                <td>'||riz||'</td>
                <td>'||kontr_tema||'</td>
                <td>'||komentar||'</td>
             </tr>      
     </table>   


         </div>

    </body> 
    </html> ';

    return vystup;
    commit;

     end;
```

Comment: Try setting min and max width (both to 750) instead of just width.

Comment: i have tried to set max width but with the same result

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829254/best-practices-for-styling-html-emails).  The problem is not in Oracle or in APEX, it is that email clients often ignore CSS headers and you should avoid them and instead use inline styling e.g.

```
<div style="width: 750px">...</div>
```

Comment: i use outlook 2010. Inline styling does not help. When i specify other parameters of div as border, font-size, color etc it works. There is only problem with width parameter.