# How to add bootstrap to CRM Dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I just wanted to ask, Is that possible to add Bootstrap to Dynamics 365 for creating Email Template?

Answer (score 0):

Basic HTML support is available while [designing Email templates](http://www.powerobjects.com/2014/07/25/using-html-format-text-email-templates-dynamics-crm/) in Dynamics CRM (365 - Customer engagement)

For advanced responsive UI/UX using Bootstrap, Probably you have to inject the stylesheets (css) with the help of CRM Developer.

[Reference](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/249233)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but not recommended. HTML emails should be designed differently to websites, due to compatibility limitations of individual email clients. [Campaign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) have a great breakdown of clients and what css they support.

Instead of loading Bootstrap in a `<style>` tag (which would be ignored by Gmail), you should use **inline styles**. See [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829254/best-practices-for-styling-html-emails) for best practices on styling HTML emails.