# html tags displayed after mail sent

Tags: php, html, css, email, phpmailer

Good day, i am having trouble with my site, on the contact page when i fill out the details and submit the form it gets processed and sends the data captured to the specified email but when the page loads it shows the page in html tags.

[This is what shows when the form has submitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlMDe.png)

and on the email side i do not get the email as styled HTML but normal

[This is what is received as email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOo1J.png)

Below is my php script that processes the form data and sends the email

```html
<?php

include 'inc/config.php';

$msg = "";
  
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {

   $name = addslashes($_POST['name']);
   $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
   $subject = addslashes($_POST['subject']);
   $message = addslashes($_POST['message']);
   
   if($name != "" && $email != "" && $subject != "" && $message != "")
   {

     require 'inc/mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
     header('Content-Type: application/json');
     
     $mail = new PHPMailer;
     
     $mail->setFrom('no-reply@kazforextraders.com', 'Kaz Forex Traders');
     
     $mail->addAddress($email);   
     
     $mail->addReplyTo('no-reply@kazforextraders.com', 'No Reply');
     
     $mail->isHTML(true);   
     
     $mail->Subject = $subject;
     
     $mail->Body    = file_get_contents('inc/contact.php');
     
     $mail->Body    = str_replace('$name', $name, $mail->Body);
     
     $mail->Body    = str_replace('$email', $email, $mail->Body);
     
     $mail->Body    = str_replace('$subject', $subject, $mail->Body);
     
     $mail->Body    = str_replace('$message', $message, $mail->Body);
     
     if(!$mail->send()) {
         
         $msg = 'Something Went Wrong. Plese Try Again! <br>Mailer Error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo.'';
         
     } else {
         
         $msg = 'Message Sent Successfully!';
         
     }    

   } 

   else

   {

    $msg = 'Please Fill out all fields!';

   }

 }

?>
```

Below is the "inc/contact.php" file. It is the file (styled HTML) that should be sent but i receive it as simple text.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="no-js oldie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="no-js oldie ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

   <!--- basic page needs
   ================================================== -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Kaz Forex Traders</title>
 <meta name="author" content="Eminential Designs">

   <!-- mobile specific metas
   ================================================== -->
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <!-- CSS
   ================================================== -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.kazforextraders.com/css/base.css"> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.kazforextraders.com/css/vendor.css"> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.kazforextraders.com/css/main.css">    

   <!-- script
   ================================================== -->
 <script src="https://www.kazforextraders.com/js/modernizr.js"></script>
 <script src="https://www.kazforextraders.com/js/pace.min.js"></script>
    <style>
 .section-intro .with-bottom-line::after {
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    width: 120px;
    height: 3px;
    content: '\0020';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -60px;
 }
 .section-intro .with-bottom-line:hover::after {
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 3px;
    content: '\0020';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -70px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
 }
 </style>

   <!-- favicons
 ================================================== -->
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://www.kazforextraders.com/favicon.png">

</head>

<body id="top">

 <!-- main content wrap
   ================================================== -->
   <div id="main-content-wrap">


  <!-- main content wrap
    ================================================== -->
    <section id="intro">

     <!-- <div class="shadow-overlay"></div> -->
     
     <div class="row intro-content">
      <div class="col-twelve">

       <h3 class="animate-intro" id="message"></h3>
       
     <div class="col-1-4 tab-full mob-full">
                    <p></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1-2 tab-full mob-full" style="padding-bottom: 13.5rem"> 
                     <img src="https://www.kazforextraders.com/images/logo.png" alt="" class="animate-intro" style="max-width: 250px;">
                    </div> 

      </div> <!-- /twelve -->         
     </div> <!-- /row -->   

  </section> <!-- /intro -->
  <section id="about">

   <div class="row section-intro group animate-this"> 
      <div class="col-twelve with-bottom-line">

       <h2 class="">New Message</h2>

      </div>   

       <p class="lead" style="text-align: left;">From: $name<br></p> 
       <p class="lead" style="text-align: left">Email: $email</p>
       <p class="lead" style="text-align: left">Subject: $subject</p>
       <p class="lead" style="text-align: left">Message: $message</p>   
       <p class="lead" style="text-align: left">This is an automated message, do not reply to it.</p>  
       <p class="lead" style="text-align: left">Regards,<br>Kaz Forex Traders</p> 

     </div>
   
  </section> 
   
   </div> <!-- /main-content-wrap -->


   <!-- footer
 ================================================== -->
 <footer id="main-footer">
     
    <div class="footer-bottom" style="padding-top: 3rem "> 

     <div class="copyright">
        <span>© Copyright Kaz Forex Traders 2018.</span> 
        <span>Developed by <a href="#">Eminential Designs</a></span>           
     </div>    
    </div>
     
   </footer>   

   <!-- Java Script
   ================================================== --> 
   <script src="https://www.kazforextraders.com/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.kazforextraders.com/js/plugins.js"></script>
   <script src="https://www.kazforextraders.com/js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Please let me know what i can do to fix this, will any appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the issue relating to the styles of the email received, most email clients including gmail, I believe won't follow links for css in the `<head>` section, what they prefer is inlined styles for emails.  As well, JavaScript will be stripped out so you can't rely on JS to style or format your html. When it comes to sending emails in HTML in general, the technology for supporting it as a modern web browser does, is simply not there yet.

Try looking into some of the tips and tricks in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829254/best-practices-for-styling-html-emails) Q&A for some suggestions to help accomplish your desired design.

As to why when the form submits you see your page in HTML, that is usually because of a Content-Type header setting how the browser should interpret this response.  Try checking the network tab in the debug tools in chrome and look at the request after submitting the form to see what the server returns as the response headers.  Also, I see in your php script that you set the header Content-Type to json, if this php script is setting that header, then including your HTML in the same request, it's possible it is the culprit.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference) is a link that explains in quite some detail about the network tab and how to use it.  Also, look into checking the setting to preserve the log so it persists between page refreshes or form submissions.