# HTML renders fine in browser but not in email (HTML is generated using pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jinja2, html-email

I am trying to send automated emails (containing tabled) in python using pandas dataframes. When I generate an HTML for the table and open it with browser, everything works great. When I try to render the same html in the email, some data is missing.

HTML rendered in browser
[image: HTML rendered in browser]

HTML rendered in Email
[image: HTML rendered in Email]

This is the code I'm using to create the HTML -

```
def csvToJinjaHTML(csvContent):

    print("Pandas: Set the max_colwidth to -1 for unlimited string length")
    pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth",-1)

    print("Pandas: Create a Pandas table from CSV content")
    pandasTable = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csvContent), index_col=False)

    # pandasTable is the dataframe that we want to beautify
    print(pandasTable)

    stylerObject = pandasTable.style

    styledHTML = (stylerObject
        .set_table_attributes('border="1" class="dataframe table table-hover table-bordered"')
        .set_properties(**{'font-size': '16pt', 'font-family': 'Calibri'})
        # .set_properties(subset=['6', '5'], **{'width': '300px'})
        .applymap(colour, subset=['ORGANIZATION'])
        .set_precision(3)
        .set_table_styles(
            [{'selector': 'tr:nth-of-type(odd)',
            'props': [('background', '#eee')]}, 
            {'selector': 'tr:nth-of-type(even)',
            'props': [('background', 'white')]},
            {'selector': 'th',
            'props': [('background', '#606060'), 
                        ('color', 'white'),
                        ('font-family', 'verdana')]},
            {'selector': 'td',
            'props': [('font-family', 'verdana')]},
            ]
        ).hide_index()
        .render()
    )

    with open('myJinjaTable.html', 'w') as f:
        print("Writing an HTML file to view the beautified Jinja table")
        f.write(styledHTML)

    return styledHTML
```

Comment: This looks like a data problem, not a rendering problem. The first row is missing columns 2 and 5 in the email.

Comment: Do you see those columns if you view the raw source of the email?

Comment: @Barmar I do see the columns in the raw source for the email. The reason I thought this was a rendering problem was that it looks fine in the browser and not in the email

Comment: Is it generating `<style>` tags in the HTML? Those are ignored in HTML email.

Comment: @Barmar this is a section from the raw source - 

```<style  type="text/css" >
    #T_d4a12ccf_83f2_11e9_92fd_787b8adf3fe8 tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
          background: #eee;
    }    #T_d4a12ccf_83f2_11e9_92fd_787b8adf3fe8 tr:nth-of-type(even) {
          background: white;
    }    #T_d4a12ccf_83f2_11e9_92fd_787b8adf3fe8 th {
          background: #606060;
          color: white;
          font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;;
```
The style tags are being generated

Comment: You should only use inline styles in HTML email, not `<style>` tags.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829254/best-practices-for-styling-html-emails

Comment: @Barmar the style tags are being auto-generated by the Pandas styler object's render method that I'm using. I couldn't find an alternate way of using inline styles with python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The lengths of the HREF links were too long apparently. I reduced the size of the links and it renders as expected.