# How to remove underline from hyperlink in outlook as well as gmail

Tags: html, css, html-email, newsletter

I am new to creating emailers. I added strong tag after anchor tag, which removed underline from outlook but now it's coming in gmail. How to disable this for both, tried a lot and gave up!

my codes are

```html
<a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#000000; text-decoration:none;"><strong>Getting Started with Our Services</strong></a>
```

gmail to gmail, outlook to outlook it's working, but when I send outlook to gmail or gmail to outlook, underline is coming in all the hyperlinks :(

Comment: [This may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829254/best-practices-for-styling-html-emails). And also [here](https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-css-inlining-in-email).

Comment: gmail to gmail, outlook to outlook it's working, but when I send outlook to gmail or gmail to outlook, underline is coming in all the hyperlinks :(

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the line of code that you are using, however you can add !important if perhaps there is something in the embedded CSS (in the `<style>` section in the `<head>`).

I.e.

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#000000!important; text-decoration:none!important;"><strong>Getting Started with Our Services</strong></a>
```

However, I suspect your issue is with the fact that you are sending emails from one service to another. If you are forwarding emails, the format changes are difficult to predict. That is not the way to test the email. You need to send the email from the HTML directly. You can do that via your ESP, or via a service such as [Putsmail](https://putsmail.com/) (by Litmus).