# Table cell width in HTML email does not correspond to width set in HTML or CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I'm trying to code an HTML email newsletter by hand (using MailChimp). It's supposed to look similar to viastedebouw.nl/newsflash/2013-06/ which was created with an app (and therefore does not have very nice looking code).

The problem that I'm having is that one of the table cells has a width set in HTML **and** CSS, but it does not correspond to either. The code is:

HTML

```
<td width="140" class="logo">
```

CSS

```
.logo { width: 140px; height: 140px; }
```

However, what ends up happening is that the logo td is 614px wide, for some reason, as illustrated by this screenshot:

[image]

The full code for the email can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Flobin/5849501

Edit: I'm now realizing I got the entire table wrong in the first place, d'oh! Most rows have 1 cell, but some have 2. I forgot to add `colspan="2"` to the cells that span the entire width of the table.

Comment: To start you off, the markup is invalid. Use a validator.

Comment: The row with the logo has 2 cells, whereas the first and remainder only have one.

Comment: @AlexK. your comment just made me realize the error is not some obscure CSS rule for email, I've got the entire table wrong in the first place. D'oh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `colspan="2"` in each cell if it is in a row by itself. As you have a row with 2 cells, all rows need to add up to 2.

Also, at the very top of your table you should also put an empty row with 2 cells to enforce the desired widths in Outlook. See [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697788/html-email-is-colspan-allowed/16964122#16964122) for more info

Comment: I was indeed missing `colspan="2"`! I didn't know about the empty row with the two cells. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply stylesheets to HTML newsletters, it needs to be inline styles!

This:

```
<td width="140" class="logo">
```

Needs to be this:

```
<td width="140"><img src="http://yourdomain.com/images/logo.png" width="140px" height="140px" /></td>
```

Or:

```
 <td width="140"><img src="http://yourdomain.com/images/logo.png" style="width:140px;height:140px;" /></td>
```

Read this thoroughly, to help you in future http://www.sitepoint.com/code-html-email-newsletters/

**Edit**

I see the inline styles!

It looks like the table width's need to be defined in order for the td's to pick up the maximum width etc.

Comment: Refer to the screenshot, OP is using inline styles for the width.

Comment: No they not, they added 'class="logo"' in the td, look carefully.

Comment: Ah yeah, I guess I forgot to mention that I'm using MailChimp, which automatically inlines all styles (which is great). Check out the screenshot, it shows this.

Comment: @msbodetti yes they are, look carefully at the screenshot. `style="width:140px..."`

Comment: Oh sorry! I see it now @MrCode

Comment: @Fobin the table the td is in needs a width so it can pick up how much space it should take up.