# Gmail Ignore HTML email table widths and styles

Tags: css, email

So, saw a bunch of posts of how gmail handles html emails ... I saw that I needed to use inline styles, and also saw a post about using spaces after ";" and ":" in my inline styles ... but I'm still running into issues. My issue is that I am designating table cell widths (30-70), but my table is still not showing the correct widths (more like 90-10 in gmail). This is mainly a gmail issue -- The styles still show in other mail clients. I've done some homework, but can't find any solutions...

[Styling HTML email for Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056172/styling-html-email-for-gmail)

[Table cell width in HTML email does not correspond to width set in HTML or CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274903/table-cell-width-in-html-email-does-not-correspond-to-width-set-in-html-or-css)

Below is how I am creating the message for the form (in PHP) ...  note the width="30%" and the inline styles (width:30%).  Still, this gets ignored in gmail. Below is a snippet of the code...

```
$to_email[] = "<TABLE style=\"font-size: 90%; \">";
        $to_email[] = "<TR>";
            $to_email[] = "<TD width=\"30%\" style=\"width: 30%; \">Column 1</TD>";
            $to_email[] = "<TD width=\"70%\" style=\"width: 70%; \">Column 2</TD>"; 
        $to_email[] = "</TR>"; // Then more code to finish the page
```

When I look at the page in google, the left width looks like it is around 90% and the right is about 10%.  Note: There are no images in the email, that would force a larger width.

When I "inspect element" and view the code in google to see the email, the code looks like this...

```
<table><tbody><tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column2></td></tr>
<!-- ... etc. -->
```

Anyone know what is wrong? As I said, the styles and everything else show up in other mail clients, so the form works fine. It's just gmail...

Note: When I save the .eml file from gmail and open it in notepad, all of the widths are there... Not sure what is going on.

Let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Those answers are obsolete; as noted in one of the answers to your first linked question, [GMail added support for `<style>` tags in 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39798471/519360). You _really_ want to use `<style>` tags. To determine whether this is a GMail issue or an HTML/CSS issue, try dumping test output to an .html file and rendering it in a modern web browser.

Comment: I read that <style> tags are removed from emails by gmail, and that you should use inline styles.

Comment: Yes, that's what the questions you linked assert, but it's no longer accurate at least according to the answer I linked. Feel free to run some tests to see for yourself.

Comment: Yup, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a good answer, so I completely restructured the form, using new headers and now the form works in google. So, check your headers...