# Colspan will support all email and mobile clients?

Tags: html, email

I am developing email responsive templates , when i developing templates shall i use colspan? it will support all desktop email clients as well mobile clients? please suggested to me, it will support or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes colspan works on all email clients if setup properly. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697788/html-email-is-colspan-allowed/16964122#16964122) may be helpful - it addresses a quirk in Outlook.

I would be cautious using multiple columns in responsive templates though. If you want something to bump down to the next line, or hide on resizing for mobile, then colspans are probably the wrong approach. A colspan cell row won't un-colspan itself, which could be problematic if you are after a single stack for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a source that explicitly states it's supprt, but yes I do believe that all email clients support the `colspan` attribute. It's a very old and basic part of HTML that is still widely used and supported by all browsers, so it's safe to assume that any email client that handles HTML also knows about colspans.

In addition I didn't find it in any of the lists of "Improvements recommended" for the email clients on this page, which can be a great resource: [email-standards.org](http://www.email-standards.org/clients/)

Sites like [this one](http://help.verticalresponse.com/how-to/tutorial/the_dos_and_donts_of_email_html/) and [this](http://www.activecampaign.com/email-design-guide/) also note that you *should* use tables, and don't list `colspan` as something that should be avoided.