# Inline CSS being stripped on <td> in Gmail (Internet Explorer) and Yahoo (Windows)

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I am building HMTL emails and I use nested tables to layout the email. To change text I apply the styles directly to the < td > tags and this works for the most part across the board. I am noticing though on SOME heavily nested tabled (Greater then 5) the style is being removed completely on Gmail in Internet Explorer, and on Yahoo in various browsers (on a PC). Below is my code:

(This code is ~5 tables deep)

```
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom:10px;font-family:'Century Gothic',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:26px; color:#202020;">The Latest</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Has anyone ran into this before or know why they might be stripping the style? It's not only text styles but the padding is also removed on these < td > tags.

Answer (score 2):

I've never had the issue myself, but there is known to be issues with nesting tables too deep. I'm willing to bet that there is a more precise way to layout your email to avoid the issue. Don't be scared to use [colspans and rowspans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697788/html-email-is-colspan-allowed/16964122#16964122) when necessary. Post your code if you like.

Comment: Gotcha thanks. I've been comfortable with colspans but I was under the impression rowspans were shady business. I'll tinker around. Thanks a bunch. 

Also I can't post my code because I'm building this for a client and I can't expose it at this point.

Comment: Rowspans always worked fine for me. Only issues I've seen are with the Outlook page break, but that is a universal issue.

Comment: For reference, here is [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859603/html-email-gaps-between-images-in-outlook-2013/19861060#19861060) of optimizing an email with colspans

Answer (score 1):

I think I may know why this is happening. I've seen issues when using a font-family with quotes throw off the inline CSS. If you move the font-family to the end of your inline styles it may work. See below.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:10px; font-size:26px; color:#202020; font-family:'Century Gothic',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">The Latest</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I've heard of this causing Outlook to default to Times New Roman - So you've found it to affect other clients also, on a scope outside of the font declaration? More info would be great...

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 1):

In case this is useful for anyone: I ran into this problem with a specific `<td>` that was getting all the inline CSS stripped. After checking it, I found I had an incorrect property declared, like so:

```
padding-bottom;
```

Removing that incorrect property resolved the issue.

It seems to me that Gmail somehow validates the css of each element, and strips it all if it finds an error.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer so my apologise, but could you not use CSS instead of HTML tables? You will be able to achieve the same result I would think?

Comment: Nope. What difference would that make?

Comment: It's a lot to explain in a comment. But an example: Outlook 2007 uses Microsoft Word as its html rendering engine.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested an html email that works for Gmail. 
Generally speaking, I learned that Gmail tends to strip out the whole inline style attribute when you declare `font-family`, this behavior sometimes happens when:

1) when you declare a custom font using `'` or `"`, es: `<span class="small-text" style="font-family:'Titillium Web',Arial,sans-serif;"></span>`

2) if don't put spaces between `;` , `,` and `:` chars, in a `font-family` declaration.

3) every time you declare 2 `<span>` with a `font-family` in the same `<td>`, Gmail will strip the second's `<span>` rules

but I don't know what is the general rule, so my solution was: **always declare font-family inside a separate tag**, at least, in this way you won't lose all the styles.

example:

```
<span style="color:#8d8c87;display:block;font-size:12px;line-height:120%;text-align:center">
    <span style="font-family:'Titillium Web',Arial,sans-serif;">text</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks @pastorello, but your code rendered the same in my tests. Interesting approach though.

Comment: gmail is quite strange about these behaviors, in my specific case I had this structure: `<td><span></span><span></span></td>`, the 2 `span` tags had the same inline style (generated by an inliner tool, 100% accuracy). Gmail decided to keep all styles on the first `<span>` and removed all inline style from the second `<span>`. Now i'm editin' my answer for completeness