# Set table width for outlook when creating responsive email

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, outlook, html-email

I have created a responsive email but I can not get outlook to recognize the width of 640 - it always expands too far. I have attempted many different options but nothing helps. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>

<title>Responsive Email Template</title>
<style type="text/css">   
  td.disclaimer {
      color:#565656;
      font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size:11px;
      width:100%;
      padding:10px;
  }
  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
      color:#019dd2;
  }
  .call-box {
      color:#ffffff;
      font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
      border:1px solid #cccccc;
      font-size:18px;
      font-weight:500;
      padding:4px;
  }
  .message-box {
      padding:10px;
      color:#565656;
      font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
      border: 1px #ffffff solid;
  }
  .media {
      border:0;
      color:#ffffff;
      font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      width:100%;
  }
  .color a {
      color:#ffffff;
  }
  .color {
      background: #019dd2;
  }
  .color-button {
      padding:4px 4px;
      color:#ffffff;
      font-size:12px;
  }
  a {
      color:#019dd2;
      text-decoration:none;
  }
  .content-left {
      width:68%;
  }
  table.container {
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 640px;
  }
  .content-right {
      width:30%;
  }
  .featured {
      width: 32%;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 500;
  }
  .featured-content {
      padding:10px;
      color:#565656;
      font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size:14px;
      background-color:#ffffff;
      font-weight:100;
      border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  }
  td.featured-content img {
      width:100%;
  }
  body {
      width:100%;
  }
  .logo {
      padding: 10px 20px;
      color:#cccccc;
      font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size:11px;
  }
  .logo-text {
      padding: 10px 20px;
      color:#cccccc;
      font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size:11px;
  }
  .message {
      padding:10px;
      color:#565656;
      font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  table.wrapper {
      width:100%;
      margin:0;
      border:0;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
      img {
          width:100% !important;
      }
      table.container {
          width:100% !important;
      }
      p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
          font-size:20px !important;
      }
      table.content-left {
          width:100% !important;
      }
      table.content-right {
          width:100% !important;
      }
      table.featured {
          width:100% !important;
          padding: 0 10px !important;
      }
      table.media img {
          width:100% !important;
      }
      td.logo p {
          font-size:12px !important;
      }
  }
  </style>
   <!--[if lte IE 9]> <style type="text/css"> 
   table.wrapper { width:640px !important; }
  </style> <![endif]--> 

  <!--[if mso]> <style type="text/css"> 
  body { width:100% !important; }
  table.wrapper { width:80% !important;}
  </style> <![endif]-->

</head> 
<body bgcolor="#f5f3f3" style="width:100%">
<table class="wrapper" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f5f5f3" valign="top" width="640">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!--START of MEDIA CONTAINER-->
            <table class="container" width="640" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" valign="top">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!--Start MEDIA-->
                        <table class="media">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3" valign="top" bgcolor="#f5f3f3" class="logo"><a href="http://monavie.com"><img src="https://www.monavie.com/sites/monavie.com/files/2013-MONAVIE.png" alt="monavie logo" border="0" style="margin-right:50px;" /></a>

                                    <table class="logo-text" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <p style="text-align:center;">SUPERHEADER
                                                    <br />Email not displaying correctly?
                                                    <br /><a href="@HTML_PREVIEW_LINK&msgVersion=web"><u><strong>View in your web browser.</strong></u></a>
                                                </p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <!--MAIN IMAGE-->
                                <td colspan="3" valign="top" bgcolor="#f5f5f3" class="main-image">
                                    <img class="main-image" src="http://my.monavie.com/sites/my.monavie.com/files/managed/ad/slider-brazil.jpg" width="100%" />
                                    <!--END of MEDIA-->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--END of image CONTAINER-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- Start Content Container-->
            <table class="container" width="640" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!--START left content-->
                        <table class="content-left" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="420">
                            <tr>
                                <td rowspan="5" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="message">
                                     <h2>Main MonaVie Title Here</h2>

                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec accumsan pharetra ornare. In porttitor suscipit turpis eu tempor. Morbi interdum lacus eget nulla luctus, eu tincidunt lectus venenatis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum eget neque lobortis lectus pharetra tempus sed vel velit. Proin ac risus sit amet ante mollis rhoncus. Sed aliquam urna id vehicula aliquam.
                                        <br />
                                        <br />Sed ipsum sapien, tempus tincidunt dui semper, rhoncus rutrum est. Sed sapien sapien, mattis sodales lacinia non, luctus non massa. Nam id fermentum ligula. Ut convallis elit nibh, eget venenatis nibh ultrices ut. Cras non convallis nunc, ac feugiat dolor. Fusce mauris enim, lacinia ac lacus et, vehicula scelerisque lorem. Maecenas ullamcorper lectus sit amet ultricies gravida. Donec nec sapien lorem. Aliquam consequat tincidunt risus ac condimentum. Integer ultricies risus sed pretium scelerisque. Nam eleifend urna at metus bibendum feugiat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean lobortis tempus ligula, nec euismod est rutrum ut.
                                        <br />
                                        <br />Ut rhoncus tellus et dapibus vehicula. In convallis ligula et orci faucibus, ac lacinia mauris varius. Etiam congue ac ligula sed vehicula. Maecenas tincidunt nulla vel eros varius, non luctus velit hendrerit. Donec tempor facilisis rhoncus. Sed non mauris odio. Praesent tempus gravida tellus quis gravida. Duis blandit varius lorem, eu mattis neque. Sed tempor sit amet nisi in convallis. Nam non aliquam massa. Sed mollis feugiat nunc, eget rutrum sem sagittis id. In ipsum diam, iaculis viverra hendrerit a, convallis pretium ipsum. Sed ac varius sapien, a tempus ligula.</p>
                                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                    <!--END of LEFT CONTENT-->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--START Right Content -->
                        <table class="content-right" align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr class="color" width="200">
                                <td class="call-box" valign="top" align="center">
                                    <p>MONAVIE EVENTS</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" bgcolor="#eeeeee" align="center" class="message-box">
                                    <p>Winners Advance Meeting
                                        <br />January 17-18
                                        <br>
                                        <br> <span class="color-button"><a href="null">READ MORE &#8250;&#8250; </a></span>
                                    </p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" bgcolor="#eeeeee" align="center" class="message-box">
                                    <p>Winners Advance Meeting Febuary 20-24
                                        <br>
                                        <br> <span class="color-button"><a href="null">READ MORE &#8250;&#8250;</a></span>
                                    </p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="323" valign="top" align="center" bgcolor="#eeeeee" class="message-box">
                                    <p>Ut rhoncus tellus et dapibus vehicula. In convallis ligula et orci faucibus.Ut rhoncus tellus et dapibus vehicula. In convallis ligula et orci faucib us.Ut rhoncus tellus et dapibus vehicula. In convallis ligula et orci faucibus.Ut rhoncus tellus et dapibus vehicula. In convallis ligula et orci faucibus.</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="color">
                                <td valign="top" class="call-box" align="center">
                                    <p><a href="null">VIEW EVENTS CALENDAR &#8250;&#8250;</a>
                                    </p>
                                    <!--END of RIGHT CONTENT-->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--END of CONTENT CONTAINER-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!--Space Start-->
            <table class="top-container" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <!--END of SPACER-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- Start FEATURED Container -->
            <center>
                <table class="container" width="640" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" valign="top">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <!--START FEATURED 1-->
                            <table class="featured" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr class="color">
                                    <td valign="top" align="center" class="call-box">
                                        <p>The MORE Project</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" class="featured-content">
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec accumsan pharetra ornare. <a href="null">READ MORE.</a>
                                        </p>
                                        <p>
                                            <img src="https://www.monavie.com/sites/monavie.com/files/styles/media_blog_image_layout/public/managed/blog/slider-more-e-book.png?itok=rbcwF_qC" alt="" width="200" />
                                        </p>
                                        <!--END FEATURED 1-->
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!--START FEATURED 2-->
                            <table class="featured" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr class="color">
                                    <td valign="top" class="call-box" align="center">
                                        <p>4x4 Jeep Program</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" class="featured-content">
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec accumsan pharetra ornare. <a href="null">READ MORE.</a>
                                        </p>
                                        <p>
                                            <img src="https://www.monavie.com/sites/monavie.com/files/styles/media_blog_image_layout/public/managed/blog/slider-mvp-lifelong-learning-jan14.jpg?itok=I_NcBiop" alt="" width="200" />
                                        </p>
                                        <!--END FEATURED 2-->
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!--Start of FEATURED 3-->
                            <table class="featured" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr class="color">
                                    <td valign="top" class="call-box" align="center">
                                        <p>Organizational Call</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" class="featured-content">
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec accumsan pharetra ornare. <a href="null">READ MORE.</a>
                                        </p>
                                        <p>
                                            <img src="https://www.monavie.com/sites/monavie.com/files/styles/media_blog_image_layout/public/managed/blog/slider-organization-call_16.jpg?itok=rsCRU69O" alt="" width="200" />
                                        </p>
                                        <!--END FEATURED 3-->
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!--END FEATURED CONTAINER -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
            <!--Space Start-->
            <table class="top-container" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <!--END OF SPACE -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!--Social Media CONTAINER -->
            <table class="container" width="640" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" valign="top">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!-- START MEDIA LINKS-->
                        <table class="media" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr class="color">
                                <td align="center">
                                    <p><a href="http://www.monavievo.com">VIRTUAL OFFICE </a>  <strong>| </strong>
 <a href="http://www.monavie.com/media">ON THE MOVE </a>  <strong>| </strong>
 <a href="http://www.monavie.com/opportunity/meetings-and-event">MONAVIE EVENTS </a>
                                    </p>
                                    <!--social media-->
                                    <table class="social-media">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="32">
                                                <img src="https://media.monavie.com/EMAIL/images/2-0_templates/facebook-blue.gif" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="32">
                                                <img src="https://media.monavie.com/EMAIL/images/2-0_templates/twitter-blue.gif" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="32">
                                                <img src="https://media.monavie.com/EMAIL/images/2-0_templates/youtube-red.gif" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="32">
                                                <img src="https://media.monavie.com/EMAIL/images/2-0_templates/instagram.png" />
                                                <!--END of social media Table -->
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!--END of social media container Table -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--DISCLAIMER CONTAINER -->
                        <table class="container" width="640" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" valign="top">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <!--DISCLAIMER START-->
                                    <table class="disclaimer" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="5" class="disclaimer">
                                                <p>To ensure that you continue to receive emails from MonaVie, please add <a href="mailto:MonaVieNews@monaviecorporate.com">MonaVieNews@monaviecorporate.com</a> to your Address Book or Safe List.
                                                    <br />
                                                    <br />This email was sent to you because you asked to receive updates from MonaVie. MonaVie emails are for informational purposes only; we will never send you an email asking for personal information. To unsubscribe from future MonaVie emails, click on the "Unsubscribe" link below.
                                                    <br />
                                                    <br />
<a href="http://email.monaviemailer.com/unsubscribe.jsp">Unsubscribe</a> |
<a href="http://www.monavie.com/privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a> |
<a href="http://www.monavie.com/">MonaVie</a> |
<a href="http://www.monavie.com/contact-us">Contact Us</a>

                                                    <br />
                                                    <br />© MONAVIE LLC 2009–2014. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</p>
                                                <!--END of disclaimer Table -->
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!--END of container Table -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--END of wrapper TABLE -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post/codepen/jsfiddle the html as it arrived in Outlook? It is hard to debug when everything is not inline.

Comment: @John I have updated the formatting. Please let me know if there is a better way of doing that. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of things in here that I believe are causing you problems.

1. Your responsive css should be formated like `*[class="container-left] { ... }`. They way your css is written right now will not work properly in most email clients.
2. I see you have a bunch of `colspans` and `rowspans`, although I've heard this can work. I've never had much luck with it. I would recommend nesting tables in tables to get the results you're looking for.
3. If consistency in email clients is of concern, I would avoid using `padding` and `margin` css. As well, all of your css styling (ie. font-family, font-size, etc..) should be inline. Not in the `head`. (I'm assuming you're not using an inliner tool.)
4. I would recommend framing your HTML a bit differently. (I've adjusted some of your html to illustrate. I didn't clean it up very much so I apologize for the extra inline css and classes. It's also not tested. But this should help get you started. ) See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dgrBA.

Comment: Here is the trick with [Colspans and Rowspans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697788/html-email-is-colspan-allowed/16964122#16964122)

Comment: Wow! You are a life saver! I've been working on that thing for six weeks! I really appreciate your help. I ran it through some test's and it works perfectly. I will be studying the changes you made so that I will better understand how it works. Thank you so much for your time and efforts!

Comment: John, I feel like we will constantly be at ends with the Colspans and Rowspans. I've never had spacing issues with nested tables. I like to think I'm pretty through with my code and when ever I approach a design/dev problem with the colspans and rowspans it usually ends with me cursing them. I find it easier to just cheat them.

Comment: Nested is usually easier to work with, but it is case by case IMO, as sometimes it is easier, and with less code with rowspans and colspans. This is particularly the case when there are overlapping elements. Here is an example of something you can't use nested tables for: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJsLH/

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) 
Does this even work on email clients? Since it can not be converted into inline style, most email clients just toss it away. I wonder if you have any luck with it?