# HTML table design does not render well on Outlook?

Tags: html, outlook

I have the following HTML table code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {
            border-spacing: 0;
        }
        thead tr {
            background: #36304a;
            color: #fff;
        }
        thead th {
            padding: 10px 25px;
        }
        thead th:first-child {
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        }
        thead th:last-child {
            border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        }
        tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
            background: #f5f5f5;
        }
        tbody td {
            padding: 10px 0 10px 25px;
        }
        .table-container {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .error {
            background: #ff6d6c;
        }
        .success {
            background: #c4e0b5;
        }
        .round-bottom {
            border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="table-container">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Criteria</th>
                    <th>Expected Value</th>
                    <th>Result</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Abc</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>500</td>
                    <td>Fail</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>kuku</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>500</td>
                    <td>OK</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>lulu</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>500</td>
                    <td>OK</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" class="round-bottom error">
                        gilbert
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="table-container">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Criteria</th>
                    <th>Expected Value</th>
                    <th>Result</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Abc</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>500</td>
                    <td>Fail</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>kuku</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>500</td>
                    <td>OK</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>lulu</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td>500</td>
                    <td>OK</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" class="round-bottom success">
                        gilbert
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

When viewing the email on Outlook, the table does not render properly:

[image]

However, on Outlook on the Web it looks fine.

I read online that Outlook uses Word to render HTML, and it has some limitations - but I'm not sure how to get around these. I tried modifying `background` property to `background-color` but it didn't do the trick.

[image]

Comment: Email clients do not typically support the full range of css that browsers do.

Comment: @Ouroborus I understand that, but there must be a workaround for this.

Comment: what about: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16964122/2008111

Comment: See: https://caniuse.email/ Of course, you can fake border radius with images and extra columns/rows.