# How make background image on newsletter in outlook?

Tags: html, background, outlook, newsletter

I'm trying to make newsletter where I have some image as background and text on it. This is easy but I need this to work on `Ms Outlook`.

What I have tried:

1.

```
<td width="100" height="100" style="background: url('someurl');">text</td>
```

2.

```
<td width="100" height="100" background="someurl">text</td>
```

3.

```
<td width="100" height="100">
    <div style="width: 0px; height:0px; position: relative;">
        <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute; background: url('someurl')">
           text
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

But nothing works well on outlook. I have no idea how fix it. I'm using outlook 2007.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try setting absolute url like url('http://www.servername.com/images/urimg.jpg')

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full Width Backgrounds on Outlook '07/'10/'13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280715/full-width-backgrounds-on-outlook-07-10-13)

Comment: @dcc this question was ask almost 2 years ago ;)

Comment: Oh. I just wanted to point out that I have a solution on the other thread in case you were still interested.

Answer (score 30):

Powerful tool for "Bulletproof Email Background Images" (VML for Outlook 2007/2010/2013, and HTML/CSS for Outlook 2000/2003, Gmail, Hotmail...)

http://emailbg.net

as an exemple :

```
    <div style="background-color:#f6f6f6;">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/n8Q6f.png" color="#f6f6f6"/>
  </v:background>
  <![endif]-->
  <table height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="left" background="http://i.imgur.com/n8Q6f.png">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

in order to have the specified background image to Full email body.

This link help to use the Vector Markup Language (VML)

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-VML#_Toc416858389](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-VML#_Toc416858389)

Comment: Consider including relevant code... so if that link ever stops working, your answer will have some value.

Comment: This solution just fixed all my problems!!

Comment: What is the solution for a background image on a div in Outlook?

Comment: Not working in Office 365 (Version 16005.11029.20108.0)..  any solution?

Answer (score 19):

you cannot add a background image to an `html` newsletter which is to be viewed in outlook. It just wont work, as they ignore the property.

You can only have block colours (`background-color`) behind text.

Outlook doesn't support the following CSS:

```
azimuth
background-attachment
background-image
background-position
background-repeat
border-spacing
bottom
caption-side
clear
clip
content
counter-increment
counter-reset
cue-before, cue-after, cue
cursor
display
elevation
empty-cells
float
font-size-adjust
font-stretch
left
line-break
list-style-image
list-style-position
marker-offset
max-height
max-width
min-height
min-width
orphans
outline
outline-color
outline-style
outline-width
overflow
overflow-x
overflow-y
pause-before, pause-after, pause
pitch
pitch-range
play-during
position
quotes
richness
right
speak
speak-header
speak-numeral
speak-punctuation
speech-rate
stress
table-layout
text-shadow
text-transform
top
unicode-bidi
visibility
voice-family
volume
widows
word-spacing
z-index
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx

**UPDATE - July 2015**

I thought it best to update this list as it gets the odd upvote every now and then - a great link to current email client support is available here: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: you need to redesign your template to use block colour behind any text, and have the image in td's around that. - basically, there is **no** way to get background images behind text in html emails that are going to an email client like outlook - the alternative is to cut the text with the image, and just show the image using the `img` tag not background

Answer (score 9):

Background DOES work in Outlook, but only in the `<body>` tag of the email. It won't work in individual `<td>`'s, only the whole email.

> UPDATE: Alternatively you can [use the VML method](http://backgrounds.cm/) which allows you
>   to add background images to individual page elements in Outlook.

This works in most clients including Outlook:

```
<body style="background-image: url('img.jpg');">
<table width="100%" background="img.jpg">
```

Here is the full code that works in all major email clients including Outlook. It has background-image set with fallback to background in a 100% width table.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
  <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-100-100-7.jpg'); background-color: #0D679C; background-position: top center;" bgcolor="#0D679C">
  <!-- BODY FAKE PANEL -->
    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-100-100-7.jpg">
      <tr>
        <td>
        <!-- CENTER FLOAT -->
          <table width="800" border="0" valign="top" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <tr>
              <td height="1000" align="center" valign="middle">
                Center panel
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        <!-- /CENTER FLOAT -->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  <!-- /BODY FAKE PANEL -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code below :

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" 
style="width: 700px; height: 460px;">
<v:fill type="tile" src="images/feature-background-01.png" color="#333333" />   
<v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">                                 
<![endif]-->
```

Note: Include this code above the table for which the background image is needed. Also, add the closing tag mentioned below, after the closing tag of the table.

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
      </v:textbox>
      </v:rect>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to do this is via this code (TD tables). I tested in outlook client 2010. I also tested via webmail client and it worked for both.

The only things you have to do is change your_image.jpg (there are two instances of this for the same image make sure you update both for your code) and #your_color.

```
<td bgcolor="#your_color" background="your_image.jpg">

<!--[if gte mso 9]>

<v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theImage" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display:inline-block; position:absolute; height:300px; width:600px; top:0; left:0; border:0; z-index:1;' src="your_image.jpg"/>

<v:shape xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theText" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display:inline-block; position:absolute; height:300px; width:600px; top:-5; left:-10; border:0; z-index:2;'>

<![endif]-->

<p>Text over background image.</p>

<!--[if gte mso 9]>

</v:shape>

<![endif]-->

</td>
```

[source](http://blog.mailermailer.com/email-design/background-images-in-html-email-the-naked-truth)

Answer (score 0):

Not all HTML and CSS is supported by Microsoft Office products, Outlook in particular; take a [look here for reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx#Word2007MailHTMLandCSS_SupportedHTMLElementsAttributesandCSSProperties) on supported elements for what you can and can't use in Outlook when rendering HTML.

Specifically, from that link it doesn't state the `background` CSS property is supported for `div` elements. You might have to use an `img` and do some hacky layering.

Note that in your second example you have a quote mismatch, which won't help any.

Lastly and something I just came across at the link provided is the [Outlook HTML and CSS Validator too](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23683)l - you could try running that against your newsletter markup and see if it gives you any suggestions/alternatives.

Comment: So the answer is? On site which you linked is position `td` which have `style` attribute. But as I say in my question it isn't work.

Comment: @MateuszRogulski Read the details for the CORE and COREEXTENDED stylesheet subset support, `background` is supported for colour only.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem a couple of months ago while working on a WYSIWYG email editor for my company. Outlook only supports background images if they're applied to the `<body>` tag - any other element and it'll fail.

In the end, the only workaround I found was to use `<div>` element for text input, then during the content submission process I fired an AJAX request with the `<div>`'s content to a PHP script which wrote the text onto a blank version of our header image, saved the file and returned its (uniquely generated) name. I then used Javascript to remove the `<div>` and add an `<img>` tag using the returned filename in the `src` attribute.

You can get all the info/methodology from the `imagecreatefrompng()` page on the [PHP Docs site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php).

Answer (score 0):

There is something explained here :

https://web.archive.org/web/20140608170948/http://www.campaignmonitor.com:80/blog/post/3363/updated-applying-a-background-image-to-html-email

Answer (score 0):

You can use it only in body tag or in tables. Something like this:

```
<table width="100%" background="YOUR_IMAGE_URL" style="STYLES YOU WANT (i.e. background-repeat)">
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Background image is not supported in Outlook.
You have to use an image and position it behind the text using position relative or absolute.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I have wrote that is not work in content of my question

Comment: position is not supported in Outlook either. See my answer for a list of unsupported CSS properties