# The image I want for my background isn't showing up in my html email code

Tags: html, html-email

I just started learning how to code up html emails yesterday and I'm having an issue with the image I want to set as the background of my html email that I send.

Here is the code at the top where i have the background image in the first table set.

If I try to add an img src tag in the tr or the td below it, the background shows but it's cut off.

Everything else works (I have buttons as images such as the one labeled "SHOP NOW!" that work fine) except the background image and this is getting frustrating!

```
<html>
<body>
<table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="711" align="center" background='http://i44.tinypic.com/21edv6q.jpg' style='vertical-align: bottom;'>
  <tr>
    <td height='588' style='vertical-align: bottom; padding-left: 20px;'>
      <a href="http://www.jbn.com/cart/index.php?route=product/categor &path=172_247" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://i43.tinypic.com/2ngvebl.jpg" alt="SHOP NOW!" />
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have your image in your body tag

```
<body background="http://i44.tinypic.com/21edv6q.jpg">
```

see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_background.asp

Comment: @user3063577 You will need it in both the body tag and wrapper table for it to work in all email clients. [Here is more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970143/how-make-background-image-on-newsletter-in-outlook/13259519#13259519).