# Thunderbird CSS Issue

Tags: html-email, thunderbird

I'm attempting to send out an HTML email from Thunderbird (latest versions), and I have an issue where when attempting to add a background-image, the url() is replaced with what looks like the beginning of a hyperlink...

An example would be:

```
#logo {
height: 427px;
width: 640px;
background: url("myimage.jpg");
}
...
<div id="logo"></div>
```

and when viewing the actual sent output I get:

```
background: url(<a class="moz-txt-link-rfc2396E" href="myimage.jpg">"myimage.jpg"</a>);
```

How can I do what I want? (I can't use an image tag in the email)

Tia!!

S.

**EDIT:**
It seems that adding a BASE solves my issue, like:

```
<base href="http://www.myurl.com" />
...
background: url("./myimage.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

That method will not work across all major email clients. There are 2 ways to put backgrounds in html emails that are widely supported (Mostly due to Outlook limitations):

VML (add to an element):
http://backgrounds.cm/

Previous Body-tag Method (only works on whole email body):
[How make background image on newsletter in outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970143/how-make-background-image-on-newsletter-in-outlook/13259519#13259519)