# Magento Images in Transactional Emails

Tags: image, magento, send, preview, transactional-email

I've created a custom transactional email. I've add a background using this.

```
<div sytle="background: {{skin url="images/myimage.png" _area="frontend" _theme="default" _package="mytheme"}}"></div>
```

It works perfectly in the preview of admin pannel, but when magento sends the email the background doesn't appear. Does anybody know why?

Comment: 1) There's a typo - should be 'style' instead of 'sytle'  
2) Which email client do you use? MS Outlook for example does not support background images as [discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970143/how-make-background-image-on-newsletter-in-outlook)

Comment: Sorry the 'sytle' was a mistake at copy the code. It is well writen in my code. I use thunderbird and doesn't appear the background but the logo either.

Comment: I see. But the CSS command is invalid anyway, it should be `background: url('path/to/image.jpg');`, in your case it is `background: path/to/image.jpg`. Try to change that aswell. Also, make sure (when previewing the email template in Magento backend) that Magento prints out an absolute URL to that image. Do so by looking at the source code.