# Bulletproof background image Outlook 2013

Tags: html, email, outlook, vml

I'm trying to put a background image on a table cell in outlook 2013.
I used this from campaign monitor : https://backgrounds.cm/ . It's supposed to work with clients working with the word html engine : outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013.

I got this code and tested it on emailonacid (only this code, nothing else) :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td background="http://www.stampready.net/dashboard/editor/user_uploads/zip_uploads/2015/11/25/uGNU4M0pzfWehDAXEvq5V6y7/stampready/images/s2_bannerbg.jpg" bgcolor="#0193F9" width="800" height="450" valign="top">
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:800px;height:450px;">
                <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.stampready.net/dashboard/editor/user_uploads/zip_uploads/2015/11/25/uGNU4M0pzfWehDAXEvq5V6y7/stampready/images/s2_bannerbg.jpg" color="#0193F9" />
                <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
        <![endif]-->
                    <div>
                    </div>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </v:textbox>
            </v:rect>
        <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now let's see the results on https://www.emailonacid.com

[image]

As you can see it works perfectly fine on 2007 and 2010, but to my disbelief it won't work on outlook 2013 even with many tries to debug it.

Maybe someone faced that problem before.

edit : as for the duplicate matter, my question concerns a problem where the  background image works in 2007/2010 but NOT 2013. This is indeed unique on stack overflow so it is not a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How make background image on newsletter in outlook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970143/how-make-background-image-on-newsletter-in-outlook)

Comment: Are you opening the actual tests to see the entire email? If not, I would suggest doing that, rather than relying on the thumbnails rendering correctly...

Comment: you're right man I was fooled by email on acid. They have some kind of problem with outlook 2013 and 2016. The tests worked fine in litmus or in client.. (the actual tests in EOA were as bugged as the thumbnails, apparently they couldn't get the image)

Answer (score 0):

Test this in an actual version of Outlook 2013. It should display the image.

Tools like Email on Acid and Litmus are essentially virtual machines. Depending on the day or time, their software could capture a screenshot before the email's images have downloaded. + It takes longer to download and display an image using MS's icky VML code.