# How to use image as a table background in email?

Tags: css, html, email, background-image, html-email

Stack Overflow users.

We run a newsletter. We need to display an image with text as a header.

We've got a massive personalization for a big user database, so we need a dynamic text overlaying a text image.

What are the options currently supported by most clients?

The obvious plan is to use table's **background-image**. Supposedly it's not working in Outlook?

There is a fallback plan that's bulletproof in terms of client support: generate an image server-side an include as graphic file. What would be the easiest way to implement it in case nothing else works?

What way would you go? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is bit off-topic and too broad for Stack Overflow. There are many resources online dealing with background-images in Outlook. Here's a handy guide on topics for SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

CSS background images are not supported in OUTLOOK, you will need to use VML,
https://backgrounds.cm/

Sometinhg like this :

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td background="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-background-with-a-3d-pattern_1319-68.jpg" width="150" height="150">
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
                style='width:150px;height:150px;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;border:0;z-index:-3;' 
                src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-background-with-a-3d-pattern_1319-68.jpg" />
            <![endif]-->
            <p>Put the rest of your content here</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here are couple of examples :

[Examlple 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970143/how-make-background-image-on-newsletter-in-outlook/13259519#13259519)

[Example 2](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_vector_markup_language_and_backgrounds)

Comment: which part of the email is this background for? Seems its to place a background around the whole email? The OP is after an image personlisation. I had edited your answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Background in Outlook works with VML only. To add an image to a table cell for personlisation i would suggest using the below code:

```html
 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td background="[IMAGE GOES HERE]" style="background:url('[IMAGE GOES HERE]'); background-image: url('[IMAGE GOES HERE]');">
   <!--[if gte mso 9]>
   <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:[ADD WIDTH OF IMAGE];height:[ADD IMAGE HEIGHT];">
  <v:fill type="frame" src="[IMAGE GOES HERE]" color="[FALLBACK COLOR]" />
  <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
   <![endif]--> 

  [HTML CONTENT HERE]

  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  </v:textbox>
   </v:rect>
   <![endif]-->
   
   
   </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

There are some values that will need changing before your VML will work properly:

- images to change
- fallback color to change
- VML height and width to change

**Note:**
When using VML your content will have to fit within the VML or there will be cases where content overflows *but will not show*. So keep in mind when this is being built. With this example you can add rounded corners with arcsize in percentages.

Hope this is the answer you were after.