# Wanting to make the local root the image the same way as using url

Tags: html, email-client

I have this piece of code, all the pieces are aligned correctly but, I am unable to get the image to work from local and be seen in the selected boxes

The URL image works. I am using this for email-clients so css cannot be used.

Can anyone help?

This is the code.

```
<table border="1" style="height:743px; width:600px;">
  <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/2010-brown-bear.jpg); width:600px; height:743px;">
            <table border="1" style="height:595px; width:420px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:90px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="margin-bottom:10px; background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/2010-brown-bear.jpg);;">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The content and title is confusing. Are you looking to get background images to show in your emails?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use image as a table background in email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525250/how-to-use-image-as-a-table-background-in-email)