# How to apply background-image to a column of table in Email template (outlook 2007)

Tags: css, email, xslt, html-email, email-templates

I have added a background-image to my column but it does not working in outlook 2007, How can I make the background-image appears in outlook 2007 clients and fill the `td` 100% and control it's positioning.

I have tried this:-

```html
<tr height="125px">
 <td width="750px" height="125px" class="tdBack" background="" align="left" valign="bottom" id="logo" style="padding:6px 80px 0px 10px;background-image: url('');background-repeat: repeat-y no-repeat;background-color: #333;margin: 0;background-size:750px">
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false">
   <v:fill type="tile" src="" />
   <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0" style="v-text-anchor:bottom;">
    <font style="font-family:Arial; font-   weith:bold;font-size:11pt; line-height: 27px;" color="#FFFFFF">
        <i>Newsletter du <xsl:value-of  select="$"/>
        </i>
       </font>
    </v:textbox>
   </v:rect>  
  </td>
  </tr>
```

but this is what I got 
[image]

I want the image fill completely the `td` and thanks!

Comment: A simple search would give you 4 answers so far on SO. Here is one that works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525250/how-to-use-image-as-a-table-background-in-email?rq=1

Comment: thank you.. but I tried already those answers and I found that outlook  2007 do not rendre the image that's inside the conditionnel comments so I  delete the conditionnel comments MSO and  it works .. problem solved thank you for the support all

Answer (score 0):

thank you.. but I tried already those answers and I found that outlook 2007 do not rendre the image that's inside the conditionnel comments **so I delete the conditionnel comments MSO** and it works .. problem solved thank you for the support all

Comment: You can render VML without conditional statement but its not advisable. Its good to use it with the conditions. If it wasnt working with condition then you condition was wrong.