# Alternatives to table background-img url for HTML emails (without the use of divs)

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I am trying to create the header section for a under construction HTML email. I am currently using `background-img url` to use the image with content overlaying it. But Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2016 does not support `background-images` on tables. I have found this [workaround](https://backgrounds.cm/) through the use of divs. However, div's are not as consistent as tables (for emails) so I want to avoid the use of `div`'s.

Is there a way to achieve this strictly though `table` structure?

**Current approach**:

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:692px; background-image: url(https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/header-image.png);" width="692" height="400">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;padding:25px 28px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                  <img alt="LOGO" src="#" style="display:block;border:0px;
                 font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#ffffff">
                </a>
              </td>
              <!-- SOCIAL ICONS -->
              <td style="text-align: right;">
                <!--YouTube -->
                <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/youtube-icon.png"></a>
                <!--Twitter -->
                <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/twitter-icon.png"></a>
                <!--LinkedIn -->
                <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/linkedin-icon.png"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/facebook-icon.png"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!----------------->
            <!-- HEADER TEXT -->
            <!----------------->
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:40px;">
                <!-- PADDING-->
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" style="height: 100px; color: #fff; font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; text-align: center; font-size: 26px; padding-bottom: 10px; text-transform: uppercase;">
                TEXT<br> HERE

              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a background image to work in Outlook 2007-2016, there is only one way it will work and that is to use Vector Markup Language (VML). It doesn't really use divs, it uses xml. The div is the wrapper.

I made a Fiddle so you can see this code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/7zLaLrfx/

This is the code:

```
<div style="background-color:#ff0000; width:600px;">
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><!-- -->
  <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.gwally.com/news/photos/catintinfoilhat.jpg" color="#ff0000"/>
  </v:background>
  <![endif]-->
  <table height="450" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="left" background="http://www.gwally.com/news/photos/catintinfoilhat.jpg">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #ffffff;-webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px; -webkit-text-stroke-color: black; font-family: Arial, san-serif;">
        Background Image with Text on Top
      </h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

What you are doing is inserting a piece of xml that directs Outlook to include a background image. Outlook will ignore your `background=""` but display the rest of the table.

This works reliably and sadly, there really is no alternative.

The original code was taken from https://backgrounds.cm with modifications.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you might be looking for. I have been eliminating divs from my code as much as possible unless i am coding hybrid. Below is a code i have customized from the link you mentioned in your post.

Your content will be the 3 tables inside the VML code. Be sure to change the width and height of the VML to make it work. Just a note as i forget at times but pick it up during testing.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
.hidden{display:none !important;}
.backgroundCover{background-size: cover; background-position:center center !important;}
}
```

```html
<table style="max-width: 600px;" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="backgroundCover" style="background: url('https://syferdoesweb.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/background-example.jpg'); background-image: url('https://syferdoesweb.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/background-example.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
<!-- [if gte mso 9]>
<v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:338px;">
<v:fill type="frame" src="https://syferdoesweb.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/background-example.jpg" color="#463783" />
<v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]-->
<table class="hidden" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="height: 70px; line-height: 0px; font-size: 0px;" height="120"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif'; font-size: 30px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; padding: 50px 10px 0px 10px;">Beautiful background in email</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif'; font-size: 20px; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; font-weight: normal; padding: 0px 0px 50px 0px;">no more crazy nights</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="hidden" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="height: 70px; line-height: 0px; font-size: 0px;" height="120"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- [if gte mso 9]>
</v:textbox>
</v:rect>
<![endif]--></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

What was done above:

- Created outer table with 3 background images placed in td. This means that every combination of the background for web is available.
- Inside the above table VML is added. Things to change on VML: Image path, image dimensions (height & width) and fall back color.
- Inside the VML comes all the HTML that is needed to style the block which will go above the background image.
- There are two extra tables added which is being used a space both the class of hidden. If media queries are read by the email client it will hide those tables.

I had written a blog post about this which can be found here: [#SyferDoesEmail](https://syferdoesweb.wordpress.com/2017/08/07/background-image-in-emails/).

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use 'background' property instead 'background-image':

```
background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat cover;
```

Comment: Still the same issue, not supported by Outlook.

Comment: So, look for this answer, it has some useful improves https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970143/how-make-background-image-on-newsletter-in-outlook

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that. As mentioned, I'd like to do it without the use of div's