# How can I insert a background image to an email template?

Tags: salesforce, email-templates, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I want to insert a background image to my email template. I dont have HTML knowledge but I can manage to follow some indications. I am working on Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Comment: Welcome to SO, the best platform for programmers needing help from other programmers. What have you tried to solve the problem so far? Please, consider to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How make background image on newsletter in outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970143/how-make-background-image-on-newsletter-in-outlook)