# support for responsive emails in Gmail App IOS

Tags: html, html-email

I stuck as to what extend the gmail app for iOS supports responsive emails. It seems to be clear that the Android version does not support it: [Responsive emails on Gmail app (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604300/responsive-emails-on-gmail-app-android)

But how about the gmail app for iOS?

I have tested the behaviour with default templates that come right out of Campaign Monitor and the app would display the web version only.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

The Gmail App seems to stripe out all css from the header (the same way the browser version does). So it doe not support media-query based responsive newsletters.

see more here https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/topic/7288/gmail-ios-app-ignores-meda-declaration-in-css/

Answer (score 3):

No version of Gmail supports the `<style>` tag, making media queries, which can't be inlined ineffective in Gmail.

If you want something more consistent across clients, most people go with a fluid layout. This pretty much limits you to single column designs though. You can set a max-width media query so that it looks like a normal 600px email in Outlook, but resizes for all devices that are smaller than 600px wide.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:
http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/the_android_mail_app_and_css_class_declarations

Others have (correctly) stated that Gmail strips out <style> tags. This is true for the Gmail app on Android and iOS, I believe.

However, it seems that the native mail app for Android does not - and that's what the URL I provided is all about.

Side note: they don't mention it, but I'm pretty sure that you can put media="all" on a <style> tag and get the same results (as opposed to using <link> or putting @media within <style>).

Cheers.