# How to make emailer/newsletter responsive?

Tags: html, css

what I am using now is :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        table[class=devicewidth] {width: 280px!important;text-align:center!important;}  
        div[class="outer"]
            {
                width:280px !important;
                display: inline-block !important;
            }
        div[class="inner"]
            {
                width: 260px !important;
                margin-left: 10px !important;               
            }
```

but it is not reflecting css styling in gmail

Comment: Take look here https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/. **<--- This your best friend**. Those selectors are not supported. And remember to use inline-styles. Here is a tool to convert CSS to inline styling. http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/

Comment: Wouldn't this be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073083/gmail-responsive-email-media-queries-style-tag?

Comment: @BrunoToffolo Yup. As said in that post: "Gmail requires all styles to be inline" here is some more information about media query support in E-Mail clients: https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/media-query-support/ and https://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/#mobile-support