# Gmail ignoring media query? - create a mobile-only div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a `<div>` only visible on mobile.

Inside the `<head>` tag I have:

```
<style>

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) {
  div[class="mobile-only"] { 
    height: 0px !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;  
  } 
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  div[class="mobile-only"] { 
    height: auto !important;
    overflow: auto !important;
}

</style>
```

And in the HTML:

```
<div class="mobile-only">
  <table...>
</div>
```

I have tried a gazillion (roughly) different ways of getting this to work, such as `display: none;` but GMail just seems to totally ignore the media query and show the `<div>` regardless.

Is there a trick to this? It works in my Outlook client.

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073083/gmail-responsive-email-media-queries-style-tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="mobile-only" style="overflow:hidden; float:left; display:none; line-height:0px;"><br/>This is hidden on desktop!</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  *[class="mobile-only"] {
    overflow: visible !important;
    float: none !important;
    display: block !important;
    line-height:100% !important;
  }
}
```

And as mentioned in the linked answer styles in html emails should be set inline.