# Equivalent to float in Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-table, html-email

I am trying to `float: left` some tables, but just encountered a major problem, outlook doesn't support float. Well, then I tried to use table align and so forth, but without luck. The tables just show up, under each other, instead of beside each other. Anything one can do about this?

PS: it works on other devices just fine, its only Outlook, and I can't give each table a td, since it will break some other stuff.

markup:

```
<table class="products">
   <tr>
      <td align="left" class="test">
         <!-- Product 1  -->
         <table align="center">
            <tr>
               <td class="product">
                  <a href="#">
                     <img src="#"/>
                  </a>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <!-- Product 2  -->
         <table align="center">
            <tr>
               <td class="product">
                  <a href="#">
                     <img src="#"/>
                  </a>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <!-- Product 3 -->
         <table align="center">
            <tr>
               <td class="product">
                  <a href="#">
                     <img src="#"/>
                  </a>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <span class="clear"></span>    
      </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: duplicated entry ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367542/in-outlook-html-email-float-does-not-work

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Set your widths on each aligned table using width="", not CSS.

An example that works:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    table td { border-collapse: collapse; }
    .msoFix { mso-table-lspace:-1pt; mso-table-rspace:-1pt; }
  </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">


<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <div style="max-width:640px !important;">

        <table class="msoFix" width="320" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
          <tr>
            <td width="15" bgcolor="454545">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="290" bgcolor="454545" align="left" style="padding: 0px;">&nbsp;<br>Table 1<br>...<br>&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td width="15" bgcolor="454545">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <table class="msoFix" width="320" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
          <tr>
            <td width="15" bgcolor="959595">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="290" bgcolor="959595" align="left" style="padding: 0px;">&nbsp;<br>Table 2<br>...<br>&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td width="15" bgcolor="959595">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body></html>
```

Also, Outlook puts a 4-5 pixel gap between the aligned tables. Adding this trims it down to about 1px:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .msoFix {
      mso-table-lspace:-1pt;
      mso-table-rspace:-1pt;
   }
</style>
```

To get rid of it completely, you'll have to add borders to your tables (another Outlook quirk hack).

Comment: This didn't work for me in Outlook 2013 (to remove the added white space from ALIGN="LEFT" tables), but just adding ALIGN="LEFT" to the IMG tag itself totally worked fine in Outlook... which is wild.

Answer (score 5):

Just put every sub-`table` into an own `td` of the outer `table`. as the `td`'s are besides each other, the `table`s will be too.

When trying to create HTML-EMails, [Code like it’s 1997](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/getting-started-with-html-emails/).

Comment: but, when the site get narrower, will it then jump down? and will it be possible to center each one on the screen, when on mobile? Cause when they are below each other, each in its own td, i dont think its possible to center them on the screen?

Comment: no, they will be besides each other on every screen. sadly, you can't do much to avoid this - HTML-rendering in EMail-Clients is often worse than IE6...

Answer (score 2):

If you can live with having the 2 tables not "responding" (one under each other) in Outlook, this worked for me:

```
........
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>
<![endif]--> 

<!-- table 1 goes here -->

<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </td>
    <td>
<![endif]-->

<!-- table 12 goes here -->

<!--[if gte mso 9]>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
........
```

Answer (score 1):

Use some online resources such as:

[How To Code HTML Emails](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/ways-to-build/about-html-email)

When it comes to rendering HTML, most email clients are primitive and will break a lot of well formed HTML elements.

The following discussion may be helpful:

[What guidelines for HTML email design are there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127498/what-guidelines-for-html-email-design-are-there)

Some basic tips:

- Use tables for layout.
- Set your widest table to be maximum of 600px wide.
- Don't try and use JavaScript or Flash
- Don't use CSS in a style tag as some mail clients will discard it.
- Use inline CSS styles only.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Outlook.com filters out `float` attributes completely, but does support `display: inline-block`.
Of course, this will most likely break your tables, as they depend on `display:table`, but it might help you with any `div`s.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been long since the OP posted this question, but I hope it helps anyone who needs it.

If you need a 2 column layout, and you want it to work in Outlook as well, then provide a `width` of around `45%` for each table (to be safe, throw in a `align="left"` too in there). If you specify the width as 50%, Outlook (which has a mind of its own) would render it as a single column.