# Need help aligning my image to be on the right and have the text wrap around it with inline CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm using inline CSS because this is for a HTML emailer. I would like my honeydew image to be aligned on the right and have the text wrap around it with some padding on the left and bottom of the image.

Can you help me fix my code?

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xBW86/

Here's my code:

```
<p>Dear Sir</p>

<img style="padding: 4px; margin: 0 0 2px 7px; display: inline;" src="http://www.fruits.com/fruits/_admin/ckfinder/userfiles/images/products/large/Honeydew.jpg" width="187" height="189" />
<p>A honeydew has a round to slightly oval shape, typically 15–22 cm (5.9–8.7 in) long. It generally ranges in weight from 1.8 to 3.6 kg (4.0 to 7.9 lb). The flesh is usually pale green in color, while the smooth peel ranges from greenish to yellow. Like most fruit, honeydew has seeds. Honeydew's thick, juicy, sweet flesh is often eaten for dessert, and is commonly found in supermarkets across the world. This fruit grows best in semiarid climates and is harvested based on maturity, not size. Maturity can be hard to judge, but is based upon ground color ranging from greenish white (immature) to creamy yellow (mature).[1] Quality is also determined by the honeydew having a nearly spherical shape with a surface free of scars or defects. Also, a honeydew should feel heavy for its size and have a waxy (not fuzzy) surface.</p>
```

Comment: I think you'll have to work with good old tables to get this to work in all (read most) email clients...

Answer (score 0):

just add `float:right` to the style

```
<img style="padding: 4px; margin: 0 0 2px 7px; display: inline;float:right;" src="http://www.fruits.com/fruits/_admin/ckfinder/userfiles/images/products/large/Honeydew.jpg" width="187" height="189" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xBW86/3/

UPDATE: 
in outlook `align="left/right"` works on the `img` tag to float images so text runs around them

P.S: also checkout `hspace` and `vspace` for some kind of margin around the image.

also read this:[In outlook html email, float does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367542/in-outlook-html-email-float-does-not-work)

Comment: Outlook 2010 doesn't recognize float right. Any other ideas?

Comment: in outlook align="left/right" works on the img tag to float images so text runs around them.