# Responsive Html Email Template

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table, html-email

I am coding *html email that should be good enough to render perfectly in all mobiles*. I  am expert in coding  emails for desktop etc.  and  this email renders perfectly in all email clients and  browsers, but I have to make it  perfect for mobiles. My code structure is as follows:

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td width="200"> <table>complete left table </table></td>
 <td width="200"> <table>complete middle table </table></td>
 <td width="200"> <table>complete right table </table></td>

</tr>
 </table>
```

To make it good for mobiles  *I know I will need media queries but  don't know to use it*, can someone refer me related tutorial that *may help me to do  my specific case*.  Please see attached image, left is for desktops, right is for  Mobiles:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: This answer has a [big list of email resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229822/best-practices-considerations-when-writing-html-emails/21437734#21437734) including responsive design links

Here are some resources on responsive design:

- [Litmus responsive how to guide](https://litmus.com/blog/the-how-to-guide-to-responsive-email-design-infographic) (scroll to bottom)
- [Campaign Monitor responsive guide](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/responsive/)

And here is a good template to get you started:

- [Email on Acid's Responsive template](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/emailology_a_free_responsive_email_template_using_media_queries_-_part_i)

Answer (score -1):

I mostly use [mjml](https://mjml.io/) (https://mjml.io/) to create the html email templates.

Check out this live example https://mjml.io/try-it-live/templates/recast

You can also try it live [here.](https://mjml.io/try-it-live)