# Overlay Image in HTML email

Tags: html, css, email

I am creating an html template, this template contains text and image. Now, we want the image to position above the text just to hide some part of the text (it has a purpose). I already tried to use absolute position for the image but it don't work when it is viewed on email. Is there any tricks to do this?

```
<div class="wrap" style="color: #4E4E4E; font-family: Calibri, Candara, Segoe, 'Segoe UI', Optima, Arial, sans-serif; max-width:600px; margin:0 auto;position:relative;">    

<div class="e_body" style="max-width:600px">
<div class="e_head" style="position:absolute; width: 100%;text-align:center;">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/EmNU0CO.jpg">
</div>

<p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</p>
<p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2fH2G/

Comment: It would help us to help you if you created a jsfiddle

Comment: jsfiddle/codepen/paste code here please :)

Comment: added code an jsfiddle link, thanks for reply.

Comment: Can you make the text as an image too ? Then I can tell an idea that would work.

Comment: To add to Johns link this is a really good resource: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: @lharby Added it to the list. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done in html email (at least consistently across clients anyway). You should read up on the limitations of html email design - [here are some resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780614/z-index-ignored-in-newsletter/19791269#19791269)

Comment: Thanks, at least I can tell this to my client. :)

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any tricks to do this?

When working with html in emails, the rules change. Most ways to position elements using css on websites do not work. What I usually end up doing is using tables to put things where they need to be, as annoying as that sounds and is to do. Also, links and images have to be full path (http://www.example.com/mypage.html instead of mypage.html) or they won't work in the sent email. Another thing is, style-sheets rarely work, and inline styles are the way to go. Basically break all the rules you knew for html on web pages.

Finally, every email client shows html emails different ways, so be aware that what you see may not be what the recipient sees. As to your specific problem though, we need to see your code.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is use the background image property in css on a cell.

For example, say I have two images. I can overlay them like so:

```
<td style="background:url('/images/image1.png');">
  <img src="/images/image2.png" />
</td>
```

Comment: This method is not supported in Outlook '07 - '13, so not plausible on a large scale. Too many people still use this email client.