# Is it possible to insert image slideshow in email?

Tags: image, email, slider

I wanna insert an image slideshow inside an email and it should be supported by all email clients. Is it possible to insert image slideshow inside an email . If yes does it work in outlook ? I have tried using JS but it is not supported in outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not include JS in html email as it is unsupported and considered spammy. Unfortunately, there is no way in HTML email to create an interactive slideshow. HTML email is very different to HTML for the web. You are limited to basic HTML and partial CSS support that both have varying levels of support across major email clients.

Read up more about the basics and limitations of html email [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780614/z-index-ignored-in-newsletter/19791269#19791269).