# Jade template not maintaining nesting

Tags: javascript, email, express, pug

I've got a jade email template. It includes a mixin file which includes the `header` mixin, which should be in all emails. It gets included properly, but due to the nesting level within it (3 levels deep), anything I put after the mixin, doesn't maintain nesting where it should.

**`views/mixins/email.jade`**

```
mixin header(siteLogo)
  div(style='margin-bottom: 20px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 20px; width: 50%; margin: 0 auto 20px;')
    div(style='text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE; padding-bottom: 10px;')
      img(src='#{siteLogo}', style='text-align: center;')
```

**`views/emails/forgot_password.jade:`**

```
include ../mixins/email

+header(siteLogo)
  p
    | Hi #{name},
  p
    | Welcome to the site!
```

Generates the email html like:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:20px;border:1px solid #ddd;padding:20px;width:50%;margin:0 auto 20px">
  <div style="text-align:center;border-bottom:1px solid #eee;padding-bottom:10px">
    <img src="path/to/image/logo" style="text-align:center">
  </div>
</div>
<p>Hi BobCobb</p>
<p>Welcome to the site!</p>
```

But I want both of those paragraph tags to be inside of the main `<div>` like:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:20px;border:1px solid #ddd;padding:20px;width:50%;margin:0 auto 20px">
  <div style="text-align:center;border-bottom:1px solid #eee;padding-bottom:10px">
    <img src="path/to/image/logo" style="text-align:center">
  </div>
  <p>Hi BobCobb</p>
  <p>Welcome to the site!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To actually answer the original question, you need to specify within the mixin where the block should render.

**`views/mixins/email.jade`**

```
mixin header(siteLogo)
  div(style='margin-bottom: 20px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 20px; width: 50%; margin: 0 auto 20px;')
    div(style='text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE; padding-bottom: 10px;')
      img(src='#{siteLogo}', style='text-align: center;')
    if block
      block
```

Answer (score 0):

Jade is useless for html email. I would strongly recommend against using any web intended framework.

Read up more on how [html email differs from the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780614/z-index-ignored-in-newsletter/19791269#19791269).

Here is what your code should look like if it is optimized for html email:

```
<table width="50%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:1px solid #dddddd">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <img alt="" src="path/to/image/logo" width="100" height="75" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000; padding:20px; border-top:1px solid #dddddd;">
      <p>Hi BobCobb</p>
      <p>Welcome to the site!</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The only template/framework I am aware of for html email is [Ink by Zurb](http://zurb.com/ink/templates.php).

Comment: I've seen ink before and do realize that using anything but tables in emails will look bad, but the main point (of what I'm trying to solve) is that I want to use mixims and partials so that I don't need to maintain an assload of the same email templates so if I change a header or footer, I can do it in a single location. It's an effort to keep things DRY.

Comment: You could try something like php include() to merge sub template files together (separate files for header, footer, 2-column section, 3-column section etc). That way you can build by mix and matching blocks.