# How to simulate z-index for newsletter?

Tags: css, newsletter

So I'm trying to reproduce this newsletter with a **button overlapping an image**.

[image]

But so far however I try I end up with something like this : [image]

[Since Z-Index is not supported by gmail](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) do you think what I want to do is possible? If yes can you redirect me to some kind of resources? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [z-index ignored in newsletter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780614/z-index-ignored-in-newsletter)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index This might help

Comment: Is it a responsive newsletter? If not, cut the white box thing and make the button part of the bottom part.

Comment: @JonasGrumann No its not however if I'm doing that I can't use the button as a link or I should use that image as well this will be a bit strange...

Comment: @PraveenPuglia Yeah I've read that already no solution in it..

Comment: I would cut the image right under the "Réserver" button, with a little bit of sky on the left and right side. Or you could place the actual button under the image in the html and then try to work with a negative margin-top to try and position it above the image.

Comment: @Frutis Can't use Position neither, I'm afraid Newsletter is just the worst headache front-dev have to deal with..