# HTML margins not supported in Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, margin

I am developing an email template which has the spacing as dynamic, so I made the position as margin, for example:

```
<td width="264px" bgcolor="#9ac5db" style="font-family:arial;font-size:12px;color:#000000;padding: 10px 5px 30px;" valign="top">
    <div name="nltitle" id="nltitle" style="font-family:arial;font-size:14px;color:#000000;display:block;text-align:center;margin:15px 0px 15px 0px;"><b>Test App</b></div>
                             
    <hr width="100%" color="#ffffff" size="3px">
                                         
    <div style="margin:10px 10px 30px 10px;text-align: left">
        Test App       
    </div>                             
</td>
```

Here I used padding and margin for setting the spaces dynamically, but it is not working in Outlook. How can I fix this issue? Any Help is highly appreciated.

Cheers,

George

Comment: For html e-mail templates use only tables if you want the same look in most e-mail clients ;) BTW you didn't close `style` tag with `"` in the first line before `valign="top"`.

Comment: @mdesdev.I forget to put that (") in the question. Is there any other method for the replacement of padding and margin because it is not working in outlook( this is because I am generating the spacing dynamically)

Comment: "Replacement of padding and margin?" you could add `<td height="30" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>` where you want top/bottom spacing also dont forget properties like `colspan` & `rowspan`.

Comment: More info about margin word around https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/outlookcom-margins/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Margin is not supported in Outlook.com, so typically you should avoid it in html email design. Instead use padding or spacer table cells with `&nbsp;` like mdesdev suggests.

A few other tips:

- You should remove the 'px' in your `width=""` declarations
- Add fallback fonts as non-windows users don't have Arial
- Instead of CSS `text-align:left;`, use HTML `align="left"`
- You don't need the divs, you can use all tables
- You may have to separate your shorthand `padding` values into `padding-top`, `padding-bottom` etc. From memory I think there might be issues writing them short hand in some email clients.

More info than you asked for, but I hope it helps...

Comment: This seemed to work across most outlooks '&nbsp;' to create spaces.

Comment: Actually, you shouldn't use `width=` or `align=` but use CSS instead. Here's some documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

Comment: @Cthulhu you are incorrect. HTML email does not follow current web standards. Here are a [bunch of references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229822/best-practices-considerations-when-writing-html-emails/21437734#21437734) on HTML email best practices

Comment: @John Thank you for that link, a lot of useful resources.

Comment: @John Does padding works in html emails ? In my knowledge, I don't think so it works for html emails.

Comment: @user5447339 Padding does but margin doesn't (for the most part). You just have to declare them separately instead of a single short-form `padding` declaration.

Answer (score 2):

the answer is simple

instead of this give

```
margin:10px 10px 30px 10px;
```

please use this

```
Margin:10px 10px 30px 10px;
```

and also Mr.George using div is not a good