# Padding and Margin not working in Responsive Email Template (outlook)

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have created one responsive email template in html. There are some styles issues.

I think **Padding** and **Margin** not working in **outlook 2007 and above**.
I have tried so many options like these below

[Margin in html not working in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347803/margin-in-html-not-working-in-outlook)

[css padding is not working in outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474239/css-padding-is-not-working-in-outlook)

I need the template with pure html (without providers like compaign monitor etc)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>A Simple Responsive HTML Email</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .content {max-width: 900px !important;}
      .dynamic_container{width: 250px !important;border:1px solid #ccc;margin-top:25px;margin-bottom:25px;margin-left:25px;margin-right:25px;}
      a{padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-left: 15px;padding-right: 15px;}
      
      @media (min-width:651px) and (max-width: 768px){
      .content {max-width: 600px !important;}
      }
      @media (min-width:0px) and (max-width: 650px){
      .content {max-width: 300px !important;}
      .dynamic_container{width: 300px !important;border:1px solid #ccc;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;}
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body yahoo bgcolor="#f6f8f1" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; min-width: 100% !important;">
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
      <style>
        .dynamic_container{width: 300px !important;border:1px solid #ccc;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;margin-left:0;margin-right:0;}
        .button > a{border-width: 10px 15px;border-color: #556401;border-style: solid;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-left: 15px;padding-right: 15px;}
      </style>
      <table width="300" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
    <![endif]-->
    <table class="content" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td class="header" bgcolor="#c7d8a7" style="padding: 40px 30px 20px 30px;">
          <table width="100" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td height="70" style="padding: 0px 20px 20px 0px;">
                <img src="assets/images/i4cfinancial_Logo.png" border="0" alt="" style="height: auto;" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="innerpadding borderbottom" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f2eeed;">
          <table class="dynamic_container" width="100%" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="comment_text" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                      Recent weeks have seen prices trending up strongly. In recent sessions the uptrend has been strong. There are indications that this instrument is short-term overbought. The last session close was an outlier to the upside.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Power Grid / Tradability </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />/<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Recent Price Action</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="10">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 15px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Learn More...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 15px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Guess to win...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="dynamic_container" width="100%" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="comment_text" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                      Recent weeks have seen prices trending up strongly. In recent sessions the uptrend has been strong. There are indications that this instrument is short-term overbought. The last session close was an outlier to the upside.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Power Grid / Tradability </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_002.png" style="height: auto;" />/<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_002.png" style="height: auto;" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Recent Price Action</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_002.png" style="height: auto;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="10">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 15px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Learn More...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 15px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Guess to win...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="dynamic_container" width="100%" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="comment_text" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                      Recent weeks have seen prices trending up strongly. In recent sessions the uptrend has been strong. There are indications that this instrument is short-term overbought. The last session close was an outlier to the upside.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Power Grid / Tradability </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_003.png" style="height: auto;" />/<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_003.png" style="height: auto;" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Recent Price Action</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_003.png" style="height: auto;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="10">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 15px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Learn More...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 15px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Guess to win...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="dynamic_container" width="100%" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="comment_text" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                      Recent weeks have seen prices trending up strongly. In recent sessions the uptrend has been strong. There are indications that this instrument is short-term overbought. The last session close was an outlier to the upside.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Power Grid / Tradability </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_004.png" style="height: auto;" />/<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_004.png" style="height: auto;" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Recent Price Action</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_004.png" style="height: auto;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="10">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 15px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Learn More...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 15px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Guess to win...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="dynamic_container" width="100%" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="comment_text" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                      Recent weeks have seen prices trending up strongly. In recent sessions the uptrend has been strong. There are indications that this instrument is short-term overbought. The last session close was an outlier to the upside.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Power Grid / Tradability </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_005.png" style="height: auto;" />/<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_005.png" style="height: auto;" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Recent Price Action</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_005.png" style="height: auto;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="10">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 15px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Learn More...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 15px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Guess to win...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="dynamic_container" width="100%" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">  
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="comment_text" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                      Recent weeks have seen prices trending up strongly. In recent sessions the uptrend has been strong. There are indications that this instrument is short-term overbought. The last session close was an outlier to the upside.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Power Grid / Tradability </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_006.png" style="height: auto;" />/<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_006.png" style="height: auto;" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Recent Price Action</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_006.png" style="height: auto;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="10">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 15px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Learn More...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 15px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Guess to win...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="footer" bgcolor="#44525f" style="padding: 20px 30px 15px 30px;">
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" class="footercopy" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff;">&copy; Someone, somewhere 2013<br/><a href="#" class="unsubscribe" style="display: block; margin-top: 20px; padding: 10px 50px; border-radius: 5px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold;"><font color="#ffffff">Unsubscribe</font></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="padding: 20px 0 0 0;">
                <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="50%" align="right" style="padding: 0 10px 0 10px;">
                      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/">
                        <img src="assets/images/fb.png" width="37" height="37" alt="Facebook" border="0" />
                      </a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="50%" align="left" style="padding: 0 10px 0 10px;">
                      <a href="http://www.twitter.com/">
                        <img src="assets/images/twit.png" width="37" height="37" alt="Twitter" border="0" />
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    <![endif]-->
  </body>
</html>
```

I have added some of the screen shot images.

In these images, **i have outline the issue with red lines**.

FYI, These red lines are not in the design

**Desktop view**[image]

**Mobile view**

[image]

**Outlook view**

[image]

Can you please explain the issues as well...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems _` display: block `_ is getting disabled or overwritten in outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Padding not working for anchor `<a>` tag in Outlook. So i have used padding for  elements in the table..

Here is the code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>A Simple Responsive HTML Email</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .content {max-width: 900px !important;}
      .dynamic_container{width: 31.33% !important;border:1px solid #ccc;margin:1%;}
      a{padding: 10px 8px !important;}
      
      @media (min-width:651px) and (max-width: 992px){
      .content {max-width: 600px !important;}
      .dynamic_container{width: 47% !important;margin:1.5%;}
      a{padding: 10px 0 !important;}
      }
      @media (min-width:0px) and (max-width: 650px){
      .content {max-width: 300px !important;}
      .dynamic_container{width: 96% !important;border:1px solid #ccc;margin:2%;}
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#f6f8f1" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; min-width: 100% !important;">
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
      <style>
        .dynamic_container{width: 32.6% !important;border:1px solid #ccc;}
        .button{padding:10px !important;}
      </style>
      <table width="100%" align="center" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
    <![endif]-->
    <table class="content" align="center" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td class="header" bgcolor="#c7d8a7" style="padding: 40px 30px 20px 30px;">
          <table width="100" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td height="70" style="padding: 0px 20px 20px 0px;">
                <img src="assets/images/i4cfinancial_Logo.png" border="0" alt="" style="height: auto;" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="innerpadding borderbottom" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f2eeed;">
          <table class="dynamic_container" width="100%" align="left" border="0" style="margin-bottom:5px;">  
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="comment_text" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                      Recent weeks have seen prices trending up strongly. In recent sessions the uptrend has been strong. There are indications that this instrument is short-term overbought. The last session close was an outlier to the upside.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Power Grid / Tradability </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />/<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Recent Price Action</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="50" valign="middle">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Learn More...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Guess to win...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="dynamic_container" width="100%" align="left" border="0" style="margin-bottom:5px;">  
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="comment_text" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                      Recent weeks have seen prices trending up strongly. In recent sessions the uptrend has been strong. There are indications that this instrument is short-term overbought. The last session close was an outlier to the upside.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Power Grid / Tradability </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />/<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Recent Price Action</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="50" valign="middle">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Learn More...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Guess to win...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="dynamic_container" width="100%" align="left" border="0" style="margin-bottom:5px;">  
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="comment_text" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                      Recent weeks have seen prices trending up strongly. In recent sessions the uptrend has been strong. There are indications that this instrument is short-term overbought. The last session close was an outlier to the upside.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Power Grid / Tradability </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />/<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Recent Price Action</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="50" valign="middle">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Learn More...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Guess to win...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="dynamic_container" width="100%" align="left" border="0" style="margin-bottom:5px;">  
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="comment_text" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                      Recent weeks have seen prices trending up strongly. In recent sessions the uptrend has been strong. There are indications that this instrument is short-term overbought. The last session close was an outlier to the upside.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Power Grid / Tradability </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />/<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Recent Price Action</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="50" valign="middle">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Learn More...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Guess to win...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="dynamic_container" width="100%" align="left" border="0" style="margin-bottom:5px;">  
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="comment_text" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                      Recent weeks have seen prices trending up strongly. In recent sessions the uptrend has been strong. There are indications that this instrument is short-term overbought. The last session close was an outlier to the upside.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Power Grid / Tradability </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />/<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Recent Price Action</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="50" valign="middle">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Learn More...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Guess to win...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="dynamic_container" width="100%" align="left" border="0" style="margin-bottom:5px;">  
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="comment_text" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                      Recent weeks have seen prices trending up strongly. In recent sessions the uptrend has been strong. There are indications that this instrument is short-term overbought. The last session close was an outlier to the upside.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Power Grid / Tradability </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />/<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Recent Price Action</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="50" valign="middle">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Learn More...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Guess to win...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="footer" bgcolor="#44525f" style="padding: 20px 30px 15px 30px;">
          <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" class="footercopy" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff;">&copy; Someone, somewhere 2013<br/><a href="#" class="unsubscribe" style="display: block; margin-top: 20px; padding: 10px 50px; border-radius: 5px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold;"><font color="#ffffff">Unsubscribe</font></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="padding: 20px 0 0 0;">
                <table border="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="50%" align="right" style="padding: 0 10px 0 10px;">
                      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/">
                        <img src="assets/images/fb.png" width="37" height="37" alt="Facebook" border="0" />
                      </a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="50%" align="left" style="padding: 0 10px 0 10px;">
                      <a href="http://www.twitter.com/">
                        <img src="assets/images/twit.png" width="37" height="37" alt="Twitter" border="0" />
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    <![endif]-->
  </body>
</html>
```

And It's working fine in web mail providers like gmail, outlook...

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are putting display inline within any class. That's why top and button margin and padding not working.

**Check below simple code in your css**

```
display:inline
```

Comment: I am not used display: inline property.

Comment: Yes. Working fine.

Comment: You can try display:block on the tag and try margin and padding .