# Email template displaying incorrectly in certain email clients

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

I created a page seen [here](http://sogmaproductions.com/email/2014/01/index.html).  From what I understand, CSS can not be used and the images must be implemented using `<table>`.  If you view the page in your browser or in certain web email interfaces, the email template looks fine.  However, certain email interfaces (Gmail for example) displays white spaces where they do not belong.  All images have border="0" and the correct image width & height.

Does anybody have any advice?  An image of the problem is available below:

[image: Screenshot of the spacing problem]

Comment: It could be a whitespace bug. Try adding `font-size: 0` to your table cells that contain only images (looks like all of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set "display:block;" style on all images

Comment: This seemed to work.  I was under the impression that inline CSS didn't work in HTML emails...I guess I was wrong.  Thank you.

Comment: You should use inline styles, tables and all old bad practices for emails, you need to think that the email is a website made for the year 1995 and you'll be fine. Divs? Css in style tags? just forget about that for emails

Comment: @Jonathan Here is a [big list of resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229822/best-practices-considerations-when-writing-html-emails/21437734#21437734) on html email design to get you up to speed on best practices.