# How does a Webmaste make a Newsletter mechanism?

Tags: html, css, email, web

I am making a small website in HTML5 which needs to have a newsletter sign up but i have no clue of how to implement this, Any way to get started with this ? I also don't have experience in MYSQL or PHP in that matter, so how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could host an existing mailing list management system such as [phpList](http://www.phplist.com) but this will require configuring the php script and setting up a mySql database for it to use.

Alternatively, you could use a mailing list service such as [mailchimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/) which is free to use for small lists, and they will provide integration code to get a signup form on your site.

Comment: Thanks, so mailchip i just like also make an HTML letter to be sent ? i mean, how do people make an individual mail letter to be sent ? does one need to be making them and feed them in the mailchimp to be sent on a timely manner?

Comment: I believe mailchip offer a range of templates or if you're confident with html email templates you could add your own. Then you can create a mailout using their system to enter in the content of your newsletter. For more info see  http://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/getting-started-with-mailchimp/  :)

Comment: @harreola If you want to learn more about creating the html, check out this [list of resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229822/best-practices-considerations-when-writing-html-emails/21437734#21437734)