# In-line scaling of images inside div tags

Tags: html, html-email

I'm trying to get my .ai email into Constant Contact through their HTML feature. When I export my slices from Illustrator, though, the quality is too low.

My solution is to export the slices as 3x the size I need and scale them down to the size I need. I'm more familiar doing this with `CSS`, but that won't work for email.

1) Is this the best solution? 2) How do I go about scaling down my images inside my `div` tags?

Here's an example of a div:

```
<div style="background-image:url(https://origin.ih.constantcontact.com/fs135/1103573722880/img/236.png?ver=1395066771000); position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:1000px; height:90px;" title="">
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing you are doing will work for email. There is no tool to slice html email cross-client friendly code. Also slicing itself is really bad practice as it results in image heavy emails which are bad. For email you need to code by hand, or use a template that was coded by hand by someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Illustrator has a "Save for web" option, but Photoshop does. Use that and export either as jpg @ 80% quality or png-24 if you need transparency.

A couple key points to remember about coding emails:

1. Although they can be, emails shouldn't be wider than 600px for maximum compatibility.
2. Background images are not supported in all browsers http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/
3. When saving your images in Photoshop/Illustrator, make sure they are sized to the dimensions you want renders. Photoshop/Illustrator will do this more effectively, better quality, and will prevent browsers and email clients from doing a crappy job and losing image quality in the process.

Answer (score 1):

In laying out your email, it may be better to avoid `div` all together and go back to the tried and true `table` layout and place image tags within the table cells as needed.

This eliminates the worry of the background image not appearing in some browsers. A good resource on building a good template can be found **[here](http://social.swiftpage.com/2013/04/23/make-it-work-best-practices-for-creating-custom-html-email-templates)**

Comment: To add to Phlume's answer, you should also never use slices, as image heavy emails can be flagged as spam, take a long time to download and do not display by default in most email clients. Here are a [lot more resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229822/best-practices-considerations-when-writing-html-emails/21437734#21437734) on html email design.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the `background-size` tag. I have also found out that adding the `no-repeat` value never hurts. So your code should look like this:

```
<div style="background-image:url('images/image.png'); background-size: 1000px 90px; background-repeat: no-repeat; position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:1000px; height:90px;" title="">
```

Answer (score 0):

in emails you should not use divs.... use a normal `img`-tag

```
<img src="https://origin.ih.constantcontact.com/fs135/1103573722880/img/236.png" width="800" height="72" alt="" style="max-width:100%;">
```

Be sure to set a `width` and a `height`!