# How to make emails responsive?

Tags: css, html-email

I am trying to send an email from my php application, How can i make the emails responsive ?

Since most of the email engines does not support linking to external css files and media queries cannot be included inline, what is an alternative solution for this ?

thanks

Comment: Emails responsive ! What do you mean ?

Comment: The solution is to link to an on-line version of your email and keep your actual email simple because most readers block many objects as standard these days (thankfully)

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen: responsive means adaptive to the screen size. See [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com).

Comment: Email template ? Use table html and inline css only

Comment: @twitterbootstrap: I know the meaning of responsive. But i just want to know whether Mahesh Eu wants email template to be responsive or wat ? (www.getbootstrap.com is the one i followed in my website - www.sysaxiom.com for responsiveness )

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen. Yes. i want the email to be responsive. it should look good on all mobile browsers and mobile clients.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen, I am not talking about website. i am talking about emails

Comment: Then i recommend you bootstrap template to use, here is the way http://www.getbootstrap.com . Here is the example of the bootstrap website http://www.sysaxiom.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not just a "simple" thing to do. There are a few frameworks and templates to help but you really need to think about your content and test a lot -

[Ink Email Framework](http://zurb.com/ink/)

Ink is the latest one on the scene. I've been working with it for about 3 weeks now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know -- responsivness is coded with [@media](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html). So in order to send a responsive email You need to be sure receiver e-mail service supports `@media`. For example gmail doesn't seem to support it, and so it is not possible if Your reciever is at gmail. I'm not sure [any service is supporting it yet](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css).

Comment: so the only way to do this is to use table and write inline css with % ?

Comment: @MaheshEu: Yep. At least that's how it appears.

Comment: Here is the [responsive support chart](http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2012/10/responsive-email-support/). You are correct that responsive is not 100% supported, while fluid layouts are. There are some links to [related info and fluid templates here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229822/best-practices-considerations-when-writing-html-emails/21437734#21437734)