# Email Campaign Problems and Testing Outlook 2007 -2010

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-2010, outlook-2007, outlook-2013

I am trying to make an email campaign display correctly in all email clients. I have tried so many fixes and ways to get my email to display write. I got it to work reasonably well on most email clients and I have tested it on Emails on acid and Campaign monitor but they don't tell we what is wrong with my code they just show me a picture which is not very Helpful.

I believe one of the main issues is that the email expands to full width in outlook 2007 and up for some reason and I cant use Max-Width attribute so I need some help.

I wondered if anyone could help out and see anything in my code that is noticeably wrong and needs to be fixed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Go City - Email</title>
<style type="text/css">
.ReadMsgBody {width: 100%;}
.ExternalClass {width: 100%;}
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
a:hover {text-decoration: none !important;}
a {color: #fff !important;text-decoration: none !important;}
p {font-size: 14px;line-height: 24px;font-family: arial, 'veranda', san-serif !important;color: #333333 !important;margin: 0px;}
span.yshortcuts {color: #000;background-color: none;border: none;}
span.yshortcuts:hover, span.yshortcuts:active, span.yshortcuts:focus {color: #000;background-color: none;border: none;}
img {border: none !important;display:block;}
.book {background: white;}
.body {max-width: 300px;}
</style>
</head>
<body marginheight="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;position:static;height:100%;width:100%;background-image:url('background-new.jpg');background-color:#000000;margin-top:0px;max-width: 630px !important;margin: auto;" bgcolor="#000000" leftmargin="0">
<!-- Outlook Bacground Image -->
<div style="background-color:#000000; max-width:630px !important;"> 
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="url('background-new.jpg')" color="#000000"/>
  </v:background>
  <![endif]-->
  <table height="100%" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="left" background="#fff"><!-- Outlook Bacground Image End --> 

        <!--100% body table-->

        <table cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="15" width="600" bgcolor="#000000" style="margin:auto;" >
          <tr>
            <td align="center"><!--top links-->

              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
                <tr height="100">
                  <td valign="middle" align="left" width="40%"><a href="https://gocityhotels.com/" style="text-decoration:none !important;color:#fff !important;"  ><img src="go-city-hotels-logo.jpg" style="display:block;" vspace="0" hspace="0" alt="Go City Hotels Logo" /></a></td>
                  <td valign="middle" align="right" width="60%" style="text-align:center;"><p style="margin:0px;color:#ffffff !important;font-family:arial, 'veranda', san-serif;line-height:24px;font-size:14px;"  >
For Better Viewing Results <webversion style="text-decoration:none;color:#10aeea !important;">Please View Online</webversion><br />
                      <forwardtoafriend style="text-decoration:none;color:#ffffff;" href="#">Forward</forwardtoafriend>
                      |
                      <unsubscribe style="text-decoration:none;color:#ffffff;" href="#">Unsubscribe</unsubscribe>
                    </p></td>
                </tr>
              </table>

              <!--email container-->

              <table bgcolor="#000000" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="30" width="600">
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding:0px;"><!--email content-->

                    <table cellspacing="0" border="0" id="email-content" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                      <tr>
                        <td><repeater> 

                          <!--section 1-->
                            <layout label="Full Width Image">
                              <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                  <td valign="top" align="center"><img editable src="" style="margin-top:10px !important;margin-bottom:10px !important;" vspace="0" hspace="0" alt="Image 3" width="100%" label="Full Width Image" /></td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </layout>
                            <!--/section 1-->

                          <!--section 2-->
                            <layout label="Colour Title">
                              <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                  <td valign="top" align="center"><h1 style="font-weight:bold;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height:40px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:0px;font-family:arial, 'veranda', san-serif;color:#ffffff;font-size:25px;background-color:#10aeea;">
                                      <singleline label="Title">Lorem ipsum</singleline>
                                    </h1></td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </layout>
                            <!--/section 2--><!--section 3-->
                            <layout label="Body Text">
                              <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                  <td valign="top" align="center"><p style="margin:0px;color:#ffffff !important;font-family:arial, 'veranda', san-serif !important;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height:22px;font-size:16px;" >
                                      <multiline label="Main Body Text">Consectetur adipiscing elit. a ipsum a risus volutpat placerat in nec mauris. Fusce sit amet enim erat, in sagittis arcu. semper id tempor et, varius pulvinar tellus. Maurtis commodo urna at dui bibendum quis euismod velit egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et.</multiline>
                                    </p></td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </layout>
                            <!--/section 3-->

<!--section 2--><layout label="3 Hotel Booking">
    <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="8" width="100%" style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <tr>


    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top" style="border-radius: 5px;width: 30%;max-width: 30%;"><p style="margin:0px;font-size:14px;text-align:center;"  ><img editable src="" style="margin-top:10px !important;margin-bottom:10px !important;" vspace="0" hspace="0" alt="Image 3" width="100%" label="Image Left" /></p>

    <p style="color:#333333  !important; font-family:arial, 'veranda', san-serif; text-align:left;"  >
      <multiline style="color:#333333 !important;" label="Main Body Text">Consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus a ipsum a risus volutpat placerat in nec mauris. Fusce sit</multiline></p>

    <p style="margin:0px;line-height:24px;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, 'veranda', san-serif;margin-top:20px;padding:5px;text-align:center;border-radius:5px;border:1px solid #0d8cbc;background-color:#10aeea;color:#ffffff !important;text-decoration:none !important;"  >
      <singleline style="color:#ffffff !important;" label="Book Now"  >Book Now</singleline>
    </p>
    </td>

    <!-- Table Padding --><td valign="top" background="#000000"></td><!-- Table Padding END -->

        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top" style="border-radius: 5px;width: 30%;max-width: 30%;"><p style="margin:0px;font-size:14px;text-align:center;"  ><img editable src="" style="margin-top:10px !important;margin-bottom:10px !important;" vspace="0" hspace="0" alt="Image 3" width="100%" label="Image Left" /></p>

    <p style="color:#333333  !important; font-family:arial, 'veranda', san-serif; text-align:left;"  >
      <multiline style="color:#333333 !important;" label="Main Body Text">Consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus a ipsum a risus volutpat placerat in nec mauris. Fusce sit</multiline></p>

    <p style="margin:0px;line-height:24px;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, 'veranda', san-serif;margin-top:20px;padding:5px;text-align:center;border-radius:5px;border:1px solid #0d8cbc;background-color:#10aeea;color:#ffffff !important;text-decoration:none !important;"  >
      <singleline style="color:#ffffff !important;" label="Book Now"  >Book Now</singleline>
    </p>
    </td>

    <!-- Table Padding --><td valign="top" background="#000000"></td><!-- Table Padding END -->

        <td bgcolor="#ffffff" valign="top" style="border-radius: 5px;width: 30%;max-width: 30%;"><p style="margin:0px;font-size:14px;text-align:center;"  ><img editable src="" style="margin-top:10px !important;margin-bottom:10px !important;" vspace="0" hspace="0" alt="Image 3" width="100%" label="Image Left" /></p>

    <p style="color:#333333  !important; font-family:arial, 'veranda', san-serif; text-align:left;"  >
      <multiline style="color:#333333 !important;" label="Main Body Text">Consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus a ipsum a risus volutpat placerat in nec mauris. Fusce sit</multiline></p>

    <p style="margin:0px;line-height:24px;font-size:14px;font-family:arial, 'veranda', san-serif;margin-top:20px;padding:5px;text-align:center;border-radius:5px;border:1px solid #0d8cbc;background-color:#10aeea;color:#ffffff !important;text-decoration:none !important;"  >
      <singleline style="color:#ffffff !important;" label="Book Now"  >Book Now</singleline>
    </p>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table></layout><!--/section 2-->

<!--section 1-->
                            <layout label="Plain Title">
                              <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                  <td valign="top" align="left"><h1 style="font-weight:bold;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height:2;margin-bottom:10px;margin-top:0px;font-family:arial, 'veranda', san-serif;color:#ffffff;font-size:25px;">
                                      <singleline label="Title">Lorem ipsum</singleline>
                                    </h1></td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </layout>
                            <!--/section 1--><!--section 5-->
                            <layout label="Image Right">
                              <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="margin:10px 0px;">
                                <tr>
                                  <td><table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td valign="top" width="50%"><p style="text-align:right;margin:0px;color:#ffffff !important;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height:22px;font-size:16px;font-family:arial, 'veranda', san-serif;"  >
                                            <multiline label="Main Body Text">Consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus a ipsum a risus volutpat placerat in nec mauris. Fusce sit amet enim erat, in sagittis arcu. Aliquam dolor dolor, semper id tempor et, varius pulvinar tellus. Maurtis commodo urna at dui bibendum quis euismod velit egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere</multiline>
                                          </p></td>
                                        <td valign="top" width="50%" style="padding-left:10px;"><img editable src="" vspace="0" hspace="0" style="display:block;" alt="Image 4" width="100%" label="Image Right" /></td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table></td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </layout>
                            <!--/section 5--><!--section 3-->
                            <layout label="Image Left">
                              <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="margin:10px 0px;">
                                <tr>
                                  <td><table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td valign="top" width="50%" style="padding-right:10px;"><img editable src="" vspace="0" hspace="0" style="display:block;" alt="Image 5" width="100%" label="Image Left" /></td>
                                        <td valign="top" width="50%"><p style="text-align:left;margin:0px;color:#ffffff !important;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height:22px;font-size:16px;font-family:arial, 'veranda', san-serif;"  >
                                            <multiline label="Main Body Text">Consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus a ipsum a risus volutpat placerat in nec mauris. Fusce sit amet enim erat, in sagittis arcu. Aliquam dolor dolor, semper id tempor et, varius pulvinar tellus. Maurtis commodo urna at dui bibendum quis euismod velit egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere</multiline>
                                          </p></td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table></td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </layout>
                            <!--/section 3--></repeater></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>

                    <!--/email content--></td>
                </tr>
              </table>

              <!--/email container--><!--footer-->

              <table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="30" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <tr style="margin-top:20px;">
                  <hr style="margin-top:30px;border:1px solid #353535 !important;"   />
                </tr>
                  <td valign="top"><p style="margin:0px;color:#353535 !important;font-family:arial, 'veranda', san-serif;line-height:24px;font-size:14px;"  > You’re receiving this newsletter because you’ve subscribed to our newsletter<br />
                      Not interested anymore?<br />
                      <unsubscribe style="text-decoration:none;color:#10aeea !important;" href="#"  >Unsubscribe instantly.</unsubscribe>
                    </p></td>
                  <td valign="top" ><a style="text-decoration:none !important;color:#fff !important;margin:5px;position:relative;float:right;display:block;height:43px;width:42px;" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/gocityhotelscom/343073452495484"> <img style="display:block;" alt="Facebook Image" vspace="0" hspace="0" src="facebook-mini-icon.jpg" /></a> <a style="text-decoration:none !important;color:#fff !important;margin:5px;position:relative;float:right;display:block;height:42px;width:42px;" href="https://twitter.com/gocityhotels"> <img style="display:block;" vspace="0" hspace="0" alt="Twitter Image" src="twitter-mini-icon.jpg" /></a></td>
                </tr>
              </table>

              <!--/footer--></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <!--/100% body table--></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
.ReadMsgBody {width: 100%;}
.ExternalClass {width: 100%;}
a:hover {text-decoration: none !important;}
a { color:#fff !important; text-decoration: none !important;}
p {font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px; font-family: arial, 'veranda', san-serif !important; color: #ffffff !important; margin: 0px;}
span.yshortcuts { color:#000; background-color:none; border:none;}
span.yshortcuts:hover,
span.yshortcuts:active,
span.yshortcuts:focus {color:#000; background-color:none; border:none;}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Also Can anyone recommend any service that would let you inspect the code or something like that to actually get to the root problem rather that just making random fixes.

Comment: If you look at services such as mailchimp they can show you how the mail will look in a large number of clients

Comment: Yes thanks for the reply, I have done this but it does not show me why my campaign is not displaying correct which is not so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2007 is the same as '10 and '13, so I'm betting you are having the same issues in all three.

Take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229822/best-practices-considerations-when-writing-html-emails/21437734#21437734) - there are a few examples of fluid templates with max width applied and working in all major email clients.

Just rip out the body and wrapper tables and you should be good to go.

Comment: I am still having trouble having tried for hours to get this working. The problem is the email is expanding to full width. And i have tried setting the width of the main table to 600px and it is still now working and i have ran out of ideas.